# Does ifelse really calculate both of its vectors every time? Is it slow?

Tags: r, performance, if-statement, vectorization

Does `ifelse` really calculate both the `yes` and `no` vectors -- as in, the entirety of each vector?
Or does it just calculate some values from each vector?

Also, is `ifelse` really that slow?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

#### Yes.  (With exception)

`ifelse` calculates both its `yes` value and its `no` value. Except in the case where the `test` condition is either all `TRUE` or all `FALSE`.

We can see this by generating random numbers and observing how many numbers are actually generated. (by reverting the `seed`).

```
# TEST CONDITION, ALL TRUE
set.seed(1)
dump  <- ifelse(rep(TRUE, 200), rnorm(200), rnorm(200))
next.random.number.after.all.true <- rnorm(1)

# TEST CONDITION, ALL FALSE
set.seed(1)
dump  <- ifelse(rep(FALSE, 200), rnorm(200), rnorm(200))
next.random.number.after.all.false <- rnorm(1)

# TEST CONDITION, MIXED
set.seed(1)
dump   <- ifelse(c(FALSE, rep(TRUE, 199)), rnorm(200), rnorm(200))
next.random.number.after.some.TRUE.some.FALSE <- rnorm(1)

# RESET THE SEED, GENERATE SEVERAL RANDOM NUMBERS TO SEARCH FOR A MATCH
set.seed(1)
r.1000 <- rnorm(1000)


cat("Quantity of random numbers generated during the `ifelse` statement when:", 
    "\n\tAll True  ", which(r.1000 == next.random.number.after.all.true) - 1,
    "\n\tAll False ", which(r.1000 == next.random.number.after.all.false) - 1,
    "\n\tMixed T/F ", which(r.1000 == next.random.number.after.some.TRUE.some.FALSE) - 1 
  )
```

**Gives the following output:**

```
Quantity of random numbers generated during the `ifelse` statement when: 
  All True   200 
  All False  200 
  Mixed T/F  400   <~~ Notice TWICE AS MANY numbers were
                       generated when `test` had both
                       T & F values present
```

---

#### We can also see it in the source code itself:

```
.
.
if (any(test[!nas]))    
    ans[test & !nas] <- rep(yes, length.out = length(ans))[test &   # <~~~~ This line and the one below
        !nas]
if (any(!test[!nas])) 
    ans[!test & !nas] <- rep(no, length.out = length(ans))[!test &  # <~~~~ ... are the cluprits
        !nas]
.
.
```

Notice that `yes` and `no` are computed only if there 
is some non-`NA` value of `test` that is `TRUE` or `FALSE` (respectively).
At which point -- and this is the imporant part when it comes to efficiency -- ***the entirety of each vector*** is computed.

---

#### Ok, but is it slower?

Lets see if we can test it:

```
library(microbenchmark)

# Create some sample data
  N <- 1e4
  set.seed(1)
  X <- sample(c(seq(100), rep(NA, 100)), N, TRUE)
  Y <- ifelse(is.na(X), rnorm(X), NA)  # Y has reverse NA/not-NA setup than X
```

#### These two statements generate the same results

```
yesifelse <- quote(sort(ifelse(is.na(X), Y+17, X-17 ) ))
noiflese  <- quote(sort(c(Y[is.na(X)]+17, X[is.na(Y)]-17)))

identical(eval(yesifelse), eval(noiflese))
# [1] TRUE
```

#### but one is twice as fast as the other

```
microbenchmark(eval(yesifelse), eval(noiflese), times=50L)

N = 1,000
Unit: milliseconds
            expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
 eval(yesifelse) 2.286621 2.348590 2.411776 2.537604 10.05973    50
  eval(noiflese) 1.088669 1.093864 1.122075 1.149558 61.23110    50

N = 10,000
Unit: milliseconds
            expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
 eval(yesifelse) 30.32039 36.19569 38.50461 40.84996 98.77294    50
  eval(noiflese) 12.70274 13.58295 14.38579 20.03587 21.68665    50
```

Comment: I +1 this because I think you have done a really thorough job of looking into this, even though I think you are comparing two different things!

Comment: btw, I am not bashing `ifelse`.  In fact, I use it all the time, except when I require efficiency.

Comment: I now understand this better. I'd give a +2 if I could. I see what you mean. It would be better for `ifelse` to use something like `rep(yes, length.out = length(ans) - sum(! test & ok ) )` instead of the default `rep(yes, length.out = length(ans))[test & !nas]` to stop unneccesary evaluations of `yes`.

Comment: the actual repeating of `yes` and `no` is negligible.  But just in assigning `yes`, `yes` gets evaluated and likewise in assigning `no` `no` is evaluated. hence the cost

Comment: There's no way to "partially" evaluate a vector in R, so there's really only one way `ifelse` could work.

Comment: @hadley, agreed. That's what spawned this whole discussion in the first place