# Complex subsetting of dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

Consider the following dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(Asset = c("A", "B", "C"), Historical = c(0.05,0.04,0.03), Forecast = c(0.04,0.02,NA))

#  Asset Historical Forecast
#1     A       0.05     0.04
#2     B       0.04     0.02
#3     C       0.03       NA
```

as well as the variable `x`. `x` is set by the user at the beginning of the R script, and can take two values: either `x = "Forecast"` or `x = "Historical"`.

If `x = "Forecast"`, I would like to return the following: for each asset, if a forecast is available, return the appropriate number from the column "Forecast", otherwise, return the appropriate number from the column "Historical". As you can see below, both A and B have a forecast value which is returned below. C is missing a forecast value, so the historical value is returned.

```
   Asset     Return 
 1     A       0.04     
 2     B       0.02     
 3     C       0.03
```

If, however, `x= "Historical"`,simply return the Historical column:

```
   Asset  Historical 
 1     A       0.05     
 2     B       0.04     
 3     C       0.03
```

I can't come up with an easy way of doing it, and brute force is very inefficient if you have a large number of rows. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: re: `ifelse`, have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16275149/1492421

Comment: Why not just fill in the `NA` values at the start of the script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, pre-process your data:

```
df2 <- transform(df, Forecast = ifelse(!is.na(Forecast), Forecast, Historical))
```

Then extract the two columns of choice:

```
df2[c("Asset", x)]
```