# Conditional Statements; creating new binary variable

Tags: r, conditional-statements

I have a pair of binary variables (1's and 0's), and my professor wants me to create a new binary variable that takes the value 1 if both of the previous variables have the value 1 (i.e., x,y=1) and takes the value zero otherwise.

How would I do this in R?

Thanks!
JMC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one example with some sample data to play with:

```
set.seed(1)
A <- sample(0:1, 10, replace = TRUE)
B <- sample(0:1, 10, replace = TRUE)
A
#  [1] 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0
B
#  [1] 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1

as.numeric(A + B == 2)
#  [1] 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0

as.numeric(rowSums(cbind(A, B)) == 2)
#  [1] 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0

as.numeric(A == 1 & B == 1)
# [1] 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0
```

---

#### Update (to introduce some more alternatives and share a link and a benchmark)

```
set.seed(1)
A <- sample(0:1, 1e7, replace = TRUE)
B <- sample(0:1, 1e7, replace = TRUE)

fun1 <- function() ifelse(A == 1 & B == 1, 1, 0)
fun2 <- function() as.numeric(A + B == 2)
fun3 <- function() as.numeric(A & B)
fun4 <- function() as.numeric(A == 1 & B == 1)
fun5 <- function() as.numeric(rowSums(cbind(A, B)) == 2)

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(fun1(), fun2(), fun3(), fun4(), fun5(), times = 5)
# Unit: milliseconds
#   expr       min        lq    median        uq        max neval
# fun1() 4842.8559 4871.7072 5022.3525 5093.5932 10424.6589     5
# fun2()  220.8336  220.9867  226.1167  229.1225   472.4408     5
# fun3()  440.7427  445.9342  461.0114  462.6184   488.6627     5
# fun4()  604.1791  613.9284  630.4838  645.2146   682.4689     5
# fun5()  373.8088  373.8532  373.9460  435.0385  1084.6227     5
```

As can be seen, `ifelse` is indeed much slower than the other approaches mentioned here. See [this SO question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16275149/does-ifelse-really-calculate-both-of-its-vectors-every-time-is-it-slow) for some more details about the efficiency of `ifelse`.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't familiar with the rowSums() function, which made the problems far easier.

Comment: It's interesting to me that you approach the issue in this way. It seems like things I've seen a number of times on SO. I think `ifelse()` is more intuitive, especially if someone has some basic programming before coming to R (not a criticism). Is there a simple reason you prefer these types of solutions?

Comment: @gung, because R is vectorized and these approaches are likely to be faster :-)

Comment: Isn't `ifelse()` vectorized? I thought it was. I know that `if(){...} else {...}` is not vectorized, & I try not to use it.

Comment: @gung, I'm out right now, but will update later with some benchmarks. I seem to remember a question about this too, so I'll try to track that down for you.

Comment: Thanks, but if it's too much trouble, don't worry about it; I'm just curious.

Comment: Don't forget this one: `as.numeric(A & B)`.

Comment: @gung, updated my answer with some benchmarks. Interesting results!

Comment: Thanks for that, @AnandaMahto, & thanks for the link. These are interesting. `ifelse()` is considerably slower. I also think it's interesting that `fun5()` has the 2nd fasted min & median, but the 2nd slowest max.