# read.csv/read.table R 3.1.1 typeconvert error

Tags: r, csv, read.table

Having updated to R version 3.1.1, `read.table`/`read.csv` incorporated in R code which ran under previous versions of R no longer works.   My original code was simply:

```
read.csv("C:/................",skip = 2,as.is= TRUE)
```

I am getting the following error:

> Error in .External2(C_typeconvert, x, na.strings, as.is, dec) :
>
> Incorrect number of arguments (4), expecting 5 for 'typeconvert'

I have tried to incorporate all the options which are required by `type.convert` ie

```
type.convert(x, na.strings = "NA", as.is = FALSE, dec = ".")
```

but to no avail. In terms of data types I have a mix of character and numeric fields but, possilbly, the most striking elements of the data are:

1)  Numeric fields have two missing indicators 'A' and 'NA'. Which is why I originally used the 'as.is' option and later used type.convert.  For example

Mean  SD
NA    0.30
NA    0.20
NA    0.30
NA    0.20
2.2   NR
1.9   NA
2.2   NA
1.9   NA
NR    NR

2) The second is that some of my character fields incorporate full stops is 'A.B'.

Has something changed in this version of R?

Comment: what are the data types in your file ? what was your original code?

Comment: Obviously lots of things have changed in this version of R or it wouldn't be a new version of R. The question is "what has remained the same in your code?". Where's your code?

Comment: Not sure why is this question is being downvoted. The code is `read.csv` that doesn't work anymore. Yesterday a guy [showed and output of an error without any code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25063354/is-there-a-limit-for-the-possible-number-of-nested-ifelse-statements-in-r) and got 8 up votes, and I don't see how this question is any worse

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I have added some detail, sorry for not originally adding this detail. Sometimes you worry your question is just so obvious.

Comment: Have you tried to set colClasses="character" ?

Comment: You should post an example of your file, just few lines reproducing the problem are enough. If it's too long copy and paste it on pastebin.com

Comment: Hello, As a quick response, it does not error anymore but I do not know if there are any down stream consequences, I will get back to you soon. Thank you ever so much.

Comment: N.B. `colClasses="character"` means that the resulting data.frame's columns will be all characters, hence after you'll need to perform your conversion on the columns (using e.g. `df$col1 <- as.numeric(df$col1)` etc.)

Comment: Thanks, this solution means that all data is now in character form.  Generally for other forum users, does this mean that I now have to import all data as character? Has R gone backwards such that it will not recognise numeric columns automatically?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after upgrading to version 3.1.1 from 3.1.0. The solution was simply to install R again.

I think the problem was that I was reckless when I migrated my installed packaged from the 3.1.0 library folder to the 3.1.1 library folder. I wrote over the standard packages such as base and utils (where the read.table function is) in the new version with the old version. When I reinstalled R it kept all the other packages I had installed.