# unexpected ')' even with matched brackets

Tags: r

I always get the following error in my code:

> unexpected `)` in
>   `ifelse(Kt_15==1&agegroup_15=="91+"&hosp_14==0&male==1,59,
>   ifelse(Kt_15==1&agegroup_15=="91+"&hosp_14==1&male==1,60,0)))))))))))`

I have about 1,000,000 observations in my dataset called `RA`. With the conditions below I want to mutate a new variable called `RG1`.
If I only use the first 10 lines and let them run, the code works perfectly fine; but 60 seems to be too much for R. I already counted the amount of brackets a dozens of times and a friend of mine double-checked them.

```
RA = RA %>%
mutate(RG1=
ifelse(Kt_15==1&agegroup_15=="19-25"&hosp_14==0&male==0,1,
ifelse(Kt_15==1&agegroup_15=="19-25"&hosp_14==1&male==0,2,
ifelse(Kt_15==1&agegroup_15=="19-25"&hosp_14==0&male==1,3,
ifelse(Kt_15==1&agegroup_15=="19-25"&hosp_14==1&male==1,4,
ifelse(Kt_15==1&agegroup_15=="26-30"&hosp_14==0&male==0,5,
ifelse(Kt_15==1&agegroup_15=="26-30"&hosp_14==1&male==0,6,
ifelse(Kt_15==1&agegroup_15=="26-30"&hosp_14==0&male==1,7,
ifelse(Kt_15==1&agegroup_15=="26-30"&hosp_14==1&male==1,8,
ifelse(Kt_15==1&agegroup_15=="31-35"&hosp_14==0&male==0,9,
ifelse(Kt_15==1&agegroup_15=="31-35"&hosp_14==1&male==0,10,
ifelse(Kt_15==1&agegroup_15=="31-35"&hosp_14==0&male==1,11,
ifelse(Kt_15==1&agegroup_15=="31-35"&hosp_14==1&male==1,12,
ifelse(Kt_15==1&agegroup_15=="36-40"&hosp_14==0&male==0,13,
ifelse(Kt_15==1&agegroup_15=="36-40"&hosp_14==1&male==0,14,
ifelse(Kt_15==1&agegroup_15=="36-40"&hosp_14==0&male==1,15,
ifelse(Kt_15==1&agegroup_15=="36-40"&hosp_14==1&male==1,16,
ifelse(Kt_15==1&agegroup_15=="41-45"&hosp_14==0&male==0,17,
ifelse(Kt_15==1&agegroup_15=="41-45"&hosp_14==1&male==0,18,
ifelse(Kt_15==1&agegroup_15=="41-45"&hosp_14==0&male==1,19,
ifelse(Kt_15==1&agegroup_15=="41-45"&hosp_14==1&male==1,20,
ifelse(Kt_15==1&agegroup_15=="46-50"&hosp_14==0&male==0,21,
ifelse(Kt_15==1&agegroup_15=="46-50"&hosp_14==1&male==0,22,
ifelse(Kt_15==1&agegroup_15=="46-50"&hosp_14==0&male==1,23,
ifelse(Kt_15==1&agegroup_15=="46-50"&hosp_14==1&male==1,24,
ifelse(Kt_15==1&agegroup_15=="51-55"&hosp_14==0&male==0,25,
ifelse(Kt_15==1&agegroup_15=="51-55"&hosp_14==1&male==0,26,
ifelse(Kt_15==1&agegroup_15=="51-55"&hosp_14==0&male==1,27,
ifelse(Kt_15==1&agegroup_15=="51-55"&hosp_14==1&male==1,28,
ifelse(Kt_15==1&agegroup_15=="56-60"&hosp_14==0&male==0,29,
ifelse(Kt_15==1&agegroup_15=="56-60"&hosp_14==1&male==0,30,
ifelse(Kt_15==1&agegroup_15=="56-60"&hosp_14==0&male==1,31,
ifelse(Kt_15==1&agegroup_15=="56-60"&hosp_14==1&male==1,32,
ifelse(Kt_15==1&agegroup_15=="61-65"&hosp_14==0&male==0,33,
ifelse(Kt_15==1&agegroup_15=="61-65"&hosp_14==1&male==0,34,
ifelse(Kt_15==1&agegroup_15=="61-65"&hosp_14==0&male==1,35,
ifelse(Kt_15==1&agegroup_15=="61-65"&hosp_14==1&male==1,36,
ifelse(Kt_15==1&agegroup_15=="66-70"&hosp_14==0&male==0,37,
ifelse(Kt_15==1&agegroup_15=="66-70"&hosp_14==1&male==0,38,
ifelse(Kt_15==1&agegroup_15=="66-70"&hosp_14==0&male==1,39,
ifelse(Kt_15==1&agegroup_15=="66-70"&hosp_14==1&male==1,40,
ifelse(Kt_15==1&agegroup_15=="71-75"&hosp_14==0&male==0,41,
ifelse(Kt_15==1&agegroup_15=="71-75"&hosp_14==1&male==0,42,
ifelse(Kt_15==1&agegroup_15=="71-75"&hosp_14==0&male==1,43,
ifelse(Kt_15==1&agegroup_15=="71-75"&hosp_14==1&male==1,44,
ifelse(Kt_15==1&agegroup_15=="76-80"&hosp_14==0&male==0,45,
ifelse(Kt_15==1&agegroup_15=="76-80"&hosp_14==1&male==0,46,
ifelse(Kt_15==1&agegroup_15=="76-80"&hosp_14==0&male==1,47,
ifelse(Kt_15==1&agegroup_15=="76-80"&hosp_14==1&male==1,48,
ifelse(Kt_15==1&agegroup_15=="81-85"&hosp_14==0&male==0,49,
ifelse(Kt_15==1&agegroup_15=="81-85"&hosp_14==1&male==0,50,
ifelse(Kt_15==1&agegroup_15=="81-85"&hosp_14==0&male==1,51,
ifelse(Kt_15==1&agegroup_15=="81-85"&hosp_14==1&male==1,52,
ifelse(Kt_15==1&agegroup_15=="86-90"&hosp_14==0&male==0,53,
ifelse(Kt_15==1&agegroup_15=="86-90"&hosp_14==1&male==0,54,
ifelse(Kt_15==1&agegroup_15=="86-90"&hosp_14==0&male==1,55,
ifelse(Kt_15==1&agegroup_15=="86-90"&hosp_14==1&male==1,56,
ifelse(Kt_15==1&agegroup_15=="91+"&hosp_14==0&male==0,57,
ifelse(Kt_15==1&agegroup_15=="91+"&hosp_14==1&male==0,58,
ifelse(Kt_15==1&agegroup_15=="91+"&hosp_14==0&male==1,59,
ifelse(Kt_15==1&agegroup_15=="91+"&hosp_14==1&male==1,60,0))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))
```

With the code above, I want to every observation a number from 1 to 60, depending on the mentioned conditions.

Comment: I think `ifelse` nesting have a limitation - around 54 or so.  A better approach would be to do a `group_by`  columns

Comment: Or create a key/val dataset with the60 combinations and do a `left_join`

Comment: This many `ifelse` calls looks like a nightmare to keep track of. Folks can help specifically if you include a [sample of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), but I suspect you'll want to switch to a) a key-value lookup like @akrun suggests, b) a `case_when`, c) collapse factor levels, or d) arrange factor levels and just make the observation number by row number. But all I can do is guess without your data.

Comment: A description of the nesting limit is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25063770/2372064. It's more a limit on the number of nested function calls in general than something that's specific to `ifelse`. It really seems like you should be doing a multi-column join instead of an ifelse anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: don't use so many nested `ifelse()` functions.
As [akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3732271/akrun) pointed out in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56153439/unexpected-even-with-matched-brackets#comment98936315_56153439): nesting may have limitations.

I always found nested `ifelse()` a bit complex to keep track anyway. For me `case_when()` works better. Documentation is [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.8/topics/case_when). The 'starwars' example in the examples of the documentation might be somewhat close to your case.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that is the code you and there is real corresponding data. Another option is mentioned by @akrun and @camille.

```
data %>% 
select(Kt_15, agegroup_15, hosp_14, male) %>%
distinct() %>%
arrange(Kt_15, agegroup_15, male, hosp_14) %>%
mutate(RG1 = row_number()) %>%
left_join(data)
```

With this code, you will get unique rows based on `Kt_15`, `agegroup`, `hosp_14`, and `male`. Then a `row_number()` will be linked to each of the aforementioned data groups. After doing that RG1 is now assigned based on these groupings.

**This is untested as you have not provided data.**