# Circumventing the ifelse() limit to insert 156 unique values to a large-scale dataframe

Tags: r, if-statement, nested

My dataframe contains 784,081 firms * 13 years = 10,193,053 unique firm_year observations (e.g. firm1_2007, firm1_2008,firm1_2009, ......, ......, firm784,081 2018, firm784,081 2019 ) from 12 home countries.

Now, I want to insert a column "gdpgrowthpercapita". I have 13 * 12=156 unique values (decimals, e.g. 3.34587) depending on year and homecountry to insert.

- First, I tried to nest ifelse() statements. This works in general, however, there is a **limit** of 50 nested statements; everything >50 does not work (see here: [Is there a limit for the possible number of nested ifelse statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25063354/is-there-a-limit-for-the-possible-number-of-nested-ifelse-statements))
- Next, I attempted to code "blocks" of ifelse() statemens for every country; however, the problem is that the **no argument** in ifelse(test, yes, no) cannot be neglected, or - to my knowledge - set in a way that it does not touch the fields where test does not apply.

How can I code my variable?

I am thankful for help! Hopefully, there is an obvious way I missed - as an R Rookie.

Thank you in advance!

Best,
Mo

Comment: Provide a small, reproducible example with a small data set, for example, 20 - 30 rows, 3 columns (year, firm, country), and 5 unique values. That will be enough to illustrate and test alternate approaches.

Comment: Have you considered using `merge` or `dplyr::left_join` rather than providing each value specifically? Sounds like you could create a small df with columns year and homecountry then join `by=c("year", "homecountry")`

Comment: left_join worked! 
I concatinated homecountry and year, and used this column as by= argument.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need to nest the `ifelse` statements - just define the column ahead of time as NA and then fill it in repeatedly. For the `no` argument, you can supply the column itself and it'll fill in the values intelligently:

```r
df <- head(data.frame(letters, LETTERS))

df$newcol <- NA
df$newcol <- ifelse(test = is.na(df$newcol) & df$letters=="a", 
                    yes = "this is an a", 
                    no = df$newcol)
df$newcol <- ifelse(test = is.na(df$newcol) & df$letters=="b", 
                    yes = "this is a b", 
                    no = df$newcol)
```

```
> df
  letters LETTERS       newcol
1       a       A this is an a
2       b       B  this is a b
3       c       C         <NA>
4       d       D         <NA>
5       e       E         <NA>
6       f       F         <NA>
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks a lot!
In the end, I went with left_join. This was easier, as it only took 5-10ish lines of code, whereas with ifelse, I would've had to enter the 156 unique gdpgrpc values for the respective country_year combinations manually. 
Thank you for your quick and effective help!

Comment: Sure! If you liked the answer, feel free to upvote and hit the green check so that others know it's helpful too.

Comment: Yes. Hit the green check. Upvoting not possible yet (as a rookie), but I´ll get there. ;-)