# Should I have if statement or ifelse?

Tags: r

I am very new in using R and trying to get my hear around different commands. I have this simple code:

```
setwd("C:/Research") 

tempdata=read.csv("temperature_humidity.csv")

Thour=tempdata$t

RHhour=tempdata$RH
weather=data.frame(cbind(hour,Thour,RHhour))
head(weather)
if (Thour>25) {
y=0 else {
y=3
}

x=Thour+y*2

x
```

I simply want the code to read the Thour(temperature) from CSV file and if it is higher than 25 then uses y=0 in the formula, if its lower than 25 then uses y=3

I tried ifelse  but it doesn't work as well.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `y = ifelse(Thour>25,0,3)` should work

Comment: i dont know r but it looks like a syntax error (unbalanced curly braces)

Comment: could use `y=3*(Thour <= 25)`

Answer (score 4):

I've said that too many times today already, but avoid `ifelse` statements as much as possible (very inefficient and unnecessary in most cases), try this instead:

```
c(3, 0)[(Thour >= 25) + 1]
```

This solution will return a logical vector of `TRUE/FALSE` which will be coerced to `0/1` when added to 1 and become `1/2` which will be the indexes in `c(3, 0)`

Or even better solution (posted by @BondedDust in comments) would be:

```
3*(Thour <= 25)
```

This solution will return a logical vector of `TRUE/FALSE` which will be coerced to `0/1` when multiplied by 3

Benchmark comparison:

```
 Thour <- sample(1:100000)
 require(microbenchmark)

 microbenchmark(ifel = {ifelse(Thour < 25 , 0 , 3)}, Bool = {3*(Thour >= 25)})
Unit: microseconds
 expr       min        lq    median        uq      max neval
 ifel 38633.499 41643.768 41786.978 55153.050 59169.69   100
 Bool   901.135  1848.091  1972.434  2010.841 20754.74   100
```

Comment: @Hank: The first suggestion is more general and would allow selection of either numeric or character vectors. The Boolean algebra approach is only effective when the desired mapping is to {0, n} where n is numeric. I used to think the Boolean algebra appraoch should be faster but in head-to-head comparisons I haven't found `ifelse` to be particularly inefficient, though.

Comment: @BondedDust, I did found `ifelse` inefficient in any benchmark I did. Ever.

Comment: I'm not sure whether my memory is failing me or `ifelse` has gotten less efficient, but the benchmark I just ran confirms the efficiency of the Boolean approach by a substantial margin. I hope you don't mind that I am editing your answer to include it.

Comment: @BondedDust, good edit for illustration. I did the same in my [previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26239328/conditional-difference-calculation-in-data-table/26243030#26243030), so got lazy to do it again in such short time period

Comment: I would not have assumed that benchmarks done in a data.table environment would necessarily translate to this situation.

Comment: @BondedDust, I did many other benchmarks before too. I can look it up if you want, but I think that your illustration will suffice for now.

Comment: A small voice of dissent: While @BondedDust's solution is quite clear, `c(3, 0)[(Thour >= 25) + 1]` is much more opaque--especially to a self-proclaimed new R user like OP. The `ifelse` statement is readable, and if the data is small enough that the performance difference in negligible, I would encourage new users to use the method that is clearest and most readable to them.

Comment: @Gregor perhaps assigning to subsets is more readable? `y <- Thour; y[Thour < 25] <- 0; y[Thour >= 25] <- 3`.  It's still slower than the Boolean approach, but much faster than `ifelse`

Comment: By the way, all of these are wrong.  The OP has `if (Thour > 25) 0 else 3`, which is the opposite sign.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you. Just replace what you're naming Thour with the appropriate code.

```
Thour <- sample(1:100, 1)
Thour
# [1] 8
y <- ifelse(Thour >= 25, 0, 3)
y
# [1] 3
```

And:

```
Thour <- sample(1:100, 1)
Thour
# [1] 37
y <- ifelse(Thour >= 25, 0, 3)
y
# [1] 0
```

You may need to change the logical operator (>=) to match your exact circumstance since it's unclear, which if any of the higher or lower range you want to be inclusive.

Answer (score 0):

R has a very flexible syntax. So you can write this in many ways:

```
# ifelse() function
y <- ifelse(Thour > 25, 0, 3)

# more ifelse()
y <- 3 * ifelse(Thour > 25, 0, 1)

# The simpler way:
y <- 3 * (Thour > 25)
```

By the way, use `<-` instead of `=` for assignment... it's the "preferred" style

Comment: The first suggestion will in general not be correct. The third one will be effective but less efficient.

Comment: @BondedDust Thanks for your feedback. AFAIK the last one (`3 * (Thour > 25)` is the most efficient, do you agree?

Comment: I have found the pure `ifelse` to be competitive with Boolean algebra.