# Ifelse behavior within data.table (R)

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table full of some consumer products. I've created some distinction for the products as `'low'`, `'high'`, or `'unknown'` quality. The data are time series, and I'm interested in smoothing out some seasonality in the data. If a product's raw classification (the classification churned out by the algorithm I used to determine quality) is `'low'` quality in period X, but its raw classification was `'high'` quality in period X-1, I'm reclassifying that product as `'high'` quality for period X. This process is done within some sort of product group distinction.

To accomplish this, I've got something like the following:

```
require(data.table)

# lag takes a column and lags it by one period,
# padding with NA

lag <- function(var) {
    lagged <- c(NA, 
                var[1:(length(var)-1)])
    return(lagged)
}

set.seed(120)

foo <- data.table(group = c('A', rep(c('B', 'C', 'D'), 5)),
                  period = c(1:16),
                  quality = c('unknown', sample(c('high', 'low', 'unknown'), 15, replace = TRUE)))

foo[, quality_lag := lag(quality), by = group]

foo[, quality_1 := ifelse(quality == 'low' & quality_lag == 'high',
                          'high',
                          quality)]
```

Taking a look at `foo`:

```
    group period quality quality_lag quality_1
 1:     A      1 unknown          NA   unknown
 2:     B      2     low          NA        NA
 3:     C      3    high          NA      high
 4:     D      4     low          NA        NA
 5:     B      5 unknown         low   unknown
 6:     C      6    high        high      high
 7:     D      7     low         low       low
 8:     B      8 unknown     unknown   unknown
 9:     C      9    high        high      high
10:     D     10 unknown         low   unknown
11:     B     11 unknown     unknown   unknown
12:     C     12     low        high      high
13:     D     13 unknown     unknown   unknown
14:     B     14    high     unknown      high
15:     C     15    high         low      high
16:     D     16 unknown     unknown   unknown
```

So, `quality_1` is mostly what I want. If period X is `'low'` and period X-1 is `'high'`, we see the reclassification to `'high'` occurs and everything is left mostly intact from `quality`. However, when `quality_lag` is NA, `'low'` gets reclassified to `NA` in `quality_1`. This is not an issue with `'high'` or `'unknown'`.

That is, the first four rows of `foo` *should* look like this:

```
   group period quality quality_lag quality_1
 1:     A      1 unknown          NA   unknown
 2:     B      2     low          NA       low
 3:     C      3    high          NA      high
 4:     D      4     low          NA       low
```

Any thoughts on what is causing this?

Comment: For starters, you don't need to reinvent the wheel. `data.table` v>= 1.9.5 already has `lag` function called `shift`, so you could simply do `foo[, quality_lag := shift(quality), by = group]`

Comment: Second of all, `ifelse` is truly an awefull function and I always trying to avoid it. My advice would be just doing something like `foo[, quality_1 := quality][quality == 'low' & quality_lag == 'high', quality_1 := "high"]`

Comment: @DavidArenburg 's point is dead on.  Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/16275149/1492421 for more info on ifelse

Comment: Thanks for the tip about `shift` in data.table v >= 1.9.5, @DavidArenburg. I'll give your suggestion a shot, since getting rid of an `ifelse` statement where I can does sound appealing.

Comment: Ah, @DavidArenburg, your solution is so simple. Not sure why I didn't think of subsetting like that. If you want to write your comments up as an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For starters, the [Development version on GitHub](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation) already has an efficient lag function called `shift` which can be used both as lag or lead (and has some additional functionality too, see `?shift`).

Take also a look [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table) as there is a bunch of other new functions that are now present in v >= 1.9.5

So under v >= 1.9.5 we could simply do

```
foo[, quality_lag := shift(quality), by = group]
```

Though even under v < 1.9.5 you could make a use of `.N` instead of creating this function in the following manner

```
foo[, quality_lag2 := c(NA, quality[-.N]), by = group]
```

Regarding your second question, I would recommend avoiding `ifelse` all together for many reasons specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16275149/does-ifelse-really-calculate-both-of-its-vectors-every-time-is-it-slow)

One possible alternative would be, just to use a simple indexing as in

```
foo[, quality_1 := quality][quality == 'low' & quality_lag == 'high', quality_1 := "high"]
```

This solution has a bit overhead, of calling `[.data.table` twice but it will still be much more efficient/safe than the `ifelse` solution.

Answer (score -3):

Your problem is that `ifelse(NA, 1, 2) == NA`, and when you do `NA == 'low'` the result is `NA`. An easy fix is to represent `NA` as strings in your lag function. Here is working version of your code:

```
require(data.table)

# lag takes a column and lags it by one period,
# padding with NA

lag <- function(var) {
    lagged <- c("NA", 
                var[1:(length(var)-1)])
    return(lagged)
}

set.seed(120)

foo <- data.table(group = c('A', rep(c('B', 'C', 'D'), 5)),
                  period = c(1:16),
                  quality = c('unknown', sample(c('high', 'low', 'unknown'), 15, replace = TRUE)))

foo[, quality_lag := lag(quality), by = group]

foo[, quality_1 := ifelse(quality == 'low' & quality_lag == 'high',
                          'high',
                          quality)]
```

Comment: You should **never** represent NA as a character mainly because `is.na("NA") # [1] FALSE`