# How to replace values between 2 arrays in R?

Tags: r, conditional-expressions

I have three arrays that have the same dimensions but what I need is to replace values in `dat1` by the corresponding values from `dat2` when only corresponding values in `dat3`  are higher than 0.2.

data:

```
dat1 <- array(1:60, c(3,5,4)) 
dat2 <- array(rnorm(60), c(3,5,4)) 
dat3 <- array(rnorm(60), c(3,5,4))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option, creating an index first and then using it to subset:

```
idx <- dat3 > 0.2
dat1[idx] <- dat2[idx]
```

Edit after comment - a small performance comparison:

```
set.seed(2015)
N <- 1e6
dat1 <- array(N, c(3,5,4)) 
dat2 <- array(rnorm(N), c(3,5,4)) 
dat3 <- array(rnorm(N), c(3,5,4))

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  ifelse = dat1 <- ifelse(dat3 > 0.2, dat2, dat1),
  index = {idx <- dat3 > 0.2
           dat1[idx] <- dat2[idx]},
  unit = "relative"
)

Unit: relative
   expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
 ifelse 5.131963 6.460236 5.545135 5.467555 33.86001   100
  index 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000  1.00000   100
```

For the sample data, indexing is ~5 times faster than ifelse.

If you have two restrictions for the replacement index just use the following index instead:

```
idx <- dat3 > 0.2 & dat3 < 0.5
```

Comment: @Barry, I haven't tested this kind of data, but in many similar/related questions subsetting with index was faster than `ifelse`.

Comment: @Barry, I added a small benchmark comparison. Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16275149/does-ifelse-really-calculate-both-of-its-vectors-every-time-is-it-slow) explaining why `ifelse` may be slow.

Comment: @Barry, I assume you don't want to replace NAs. Try this instead: `idx <- dat3 > 0.2 & !is.na(dat3)` to build the index

Answer (score 4):

```
ifelse(dat3 > 0.2, dat2, dat1)
```

Comment: Just put the new boolean in there. `dat3 > 0.2 & dat3 < 0.5`