# Why doesn't this conditional lookup work?

Tags: r, data.table

EDIT: Revamped reflecting comments below

I've got some data on workers across time. They may work in more than one position in any given year; I want to subset the data to get workers who have *at least one* position with certain characteristics.

Here's my toy data:

```
set.seed(1643)
dt<-data.table(id=rep(1:1000,10),
               area=sample(letters,1e4,replace=T),
               position=sample(10,1e4,replace=T),
               firm_type=sample(5,1e4,replace=T),
               year=rep(2001:2010,each=1000),key="id")
```

I only want workers in `area` `d`,`o`,`w`,`l`,`e` at `position` `7`.

Unfortunately, the way that `firm_type` was coded changed from 2005 onwards; prior to 2005, the relevant workers were all at firms with `firm_type==1`. Thereafter, types `1` and `2` are acceptable.

I tried this look-up but it doesn't work:

```
dt[.(dt[firm_type %in% ifelse(year<2005,1,1:2)
    &area %in% c("d","o","w","l","e")
    &position==7,unique(id)])]
```

Specifically, the `%in%` operator, as mentioned in the comments below, can't operate row-by-row, so we get (intermediate) output like:

```
> dt[firm_type %in% ifelse(year<2005,1,1:2)
+    &area %in% c("d","o","w","l","e")
+    &position==7,table(firm_type,year)]
         year
firm_type 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010
        1    4    2    5    2    3    7    1    0    4    1
        2    2    4    4    6    4    5    9    8    1    2
```

@Frank inspired this workaround:

```
dt[.(dt[ifelse(year<2005,firm_type==1,
           firm_type %in% 1:2)
    &area %in% c("d","o","w","l","e")
    &position==7,unique(id)])]
```

I'm content with this, but I was encouraged to see if there's a better approach to this problem because `ifelse` is not optimized.

Comment: `ifelse` won't return a vector from one conditional, it will just give you the first letter back

Comment: Yeah, the `ifelse` you've written is the same as `ifelse(yr<2005,rep(letters[1:2],1000/2),rep(letters[3:4],1000/2))`. If that is what you were going for, just use extra parens (in 1.9.4), like `dt[(grp%in%X)]`

Comment: @6pool this doesn't agree with the output we see... if that were the case `b` and `d` would be 0d out appropriately

Comment: @Frank in my actual example, the `dt` is keyed by a different variable, so I don't think that syntax will work

Comment: I'm making the same point 6pool is: you cannot have different right-hand sides of `%in%` for each row. It's not vectorized in that way. The `ifelse` evaluates to a single vector, and that is what is used as the RHS.

Comment: You shouldn't use `ifelse` in `data.table` anyway (at least until Arun and Matt optimize it). It's inefficient.

Comment: @Roland see the update at the bottom of my question; I don't think I can do the search I need to do in a binary fashion...

Comment: @Frank thanks, that's the key. This works: `dt[ifelse(yr<2005,grp %in% letters[1:2],grp %in% letters[3:4]),]`

Comment: I'm not sure what the best alternative to `ifelse` is here. Your `|` requires both vectors to be constructed, while you could alternately do `dt[yr<2005,tag:=grp%in%letters[1:2]][yr>=2005,tag:=grp%in%letters[3:4]][(tag)]`

Comment: I think the efficiency improvement is not large if there is any, though (since `[` has overhead). I'd probably consider just doing the `ifelse` from your last comment. Dunno what @Roland thinks.

Comment: anyway this is a one-time operation, so the efficiency loss is not too painful

Comment: @Frank `ifelse` means copies. That's slow.

Comment: @MichaelChirico  I think this question would benefit from a full and clear problem description, which would enable people to suggest alternative approaches. (And please set the random seed!)

Comment: Are you using 1.9.4? If so it should be the auto indexing bug... that's fixed in 1.9.5.

Comment: @Roland check out the updated question. As I was writing it, @Frank's suggestion to just defined a `tag` indicator began to seem more appealing--though I always hate defining one-time-use indicators due to clutter

Comment: If it's a subsetting operation you're after, why are you doing a join `dt[.(dt[...])]`? Are you just trying to select `id`s that meet the criterion?

Comment: In essence, yes; should I ellaborate on this: "I want to subset the data to get workers who have at least one position with certain characteristics"

Comment: Yeah, that clarifies it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A faster way.** You could defer the `ifelse` until you have a smaller subset:

```
dt[ position==7L & area%in%c("d","o","w","l","e") & firm_type%in%1:2
][ifelse(year<2005,firm_type==1L,firm_type %in% 1:2),
  unique(id)
]
```

Depending on how readable you find it, you could also do:

```
dt[ position==7L & area%in%c("d","o","w","l","e") & firm_type%in%1:2
][!(year < 2005 & firm_type==2L),
  unique(id)
]
```

*Regarding ifelse.* `ifelse(cond,yes,no)` is slow because it calculates all of `yes` and `no` if it needs either of them, as [documented by @RicardoSaporta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16275149/1191259). Another idea -- `(cond&yes)|((!cond)&no)` -- mentioned in an earlier iteration of the OP, has the same problem.

---

**The verbose way.** If your conditions are messier, you might want to make them explicit:

```
my_areas     = c("d","o","w","l","e")
my_posns     = 7L
my_yearfirms = data.table(year=unique(dt$year))[,.(
  firm_type = if (year<2005) 1L else 1:2
),by=year]

merge(dt[position%in%my_posns & area%in%my_areas],my_yearfirms,by=c("year","firm_type"))[,
  unique(id)
]
```

The final piece of code can be

- skipped over (guessing what is going on by context) and
- reused elsewhere (if you change your conditions).

This is what I would do unless efficiency was very important.

Answer (score 0):

Just use an "or" in addition to "and":

```
> dt[((firm_type == 1 ) | (firm_type ==2 & year>=2005))
+    &area %in% c("d","o","w","l","e")
+    &position==7,]
```