# Read blank as missing(NA) in R data table

Tags: r, function, data.table

I am trying to create a function which can find missing location and impute the missing in a data table. Now this function uses `is.na()` extensively to find out the missing location and also to replace it with imputation value. It is working fine for all type of variable until input is `character` type column and have blank cells as missing, because `is.na()` is not able to identify it as missing hence it skips these cells for imputation.

Example:

```
    library(data.table)
    t<-data.table(x=c('an','ax','','az'),y=c('bn','','bz','bx'))
          x  y
      1: an bn
      2: ax      
      3:    bz 
      4: az bx
      is.na(t[,x])
      [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

where it should be

```
      [1] FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and the expected result.  For guidelines, check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).  If you have `''` as missing. then `yourdf$yourCol==''` should give the logical TRUE/FALSE for `''`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the fast `nzchar` like this :

```
is.na(x) | !nzchar(x)
```

For example :

```
x <- c(NA,'','a')
is.na(x) | !nzchar(x) 
## [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

### apply this to OP example:

I wrap this in a function with `ifelse` :

```
tt <- data.table(x=c('an','ax','','az'),y=c('bn','','bz','bx'))
tt[, lapply(.SD,
            function(x)
              ifelse(is.na(x) | !nzchar(x),'some value',x)) ]

           x          y
1:         an         bn
2:         ax some value
3: some value         bz
4:         az         bx
```

Comment: I don't think this could work for data tables. I tried to use your code on my data table but it gives the same result. nzchar(test_dt)
[1] TRUE        Although it works perfect for vector type input.

Comment: @Anuj that's wahy you should give a reproducible example dn the desired output. Even if you did it later, but you example is still not reproducible. Can you use `dput` to add your data? Please take the time to read the link  in the comment below your question.

Comment: I have added reproducible example. Sorry for the confusion, I am new to stackoverflow. Also your solution is working fine if I use it like this is.na(t[,x]| !nzchar(t[,x]) but when I call the column using index, it gives the same result.

Comment: @Anuj no roblem. You are welcome. I add a solution using your data.

Comment: Instead of `ifelse` (which has something of a rep for being slow), one could use `replace(x, which(is.na(x) | !nzchar(x)), 'some value')`

Comment: @Frank Interesting. Can you add some benchmarking please?

Comment: @agstudy The claim about it being slow is based on Ricardo Saporta's post here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16275149/1191259 I don't think it actually applies to your answer, but more to cases like `ifelse(cond,costly_calculation,costly_calculation2)` since both costly calculations have to be made in their entirety even though only a part of each is used.

Comment: Oh actually, here's a benchmark for a similar case to yours where its 10x as slow: `x <- sample(1:2,1e7,replace=TRUE); system.time(replace(x,which(x==2L),0L)); system.time(ifelse(x==2L,0L,x))`

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using conditional assignment (using `i`):

```
DT <- data.table(x = c('an','ax','','az',NA),
                 y = c(NA,'bn','','bz','bx'))
DT[x %in% c(NA, ""), x := 'some value']
DT[y %in% c(NA, ""), y := 'some value']
```

Result:

```
            x          y
1:         an some value
2:         ax         bn
3: some value some value
4:         az         bz
5: some value         bx
```