# dplyr on subset of columns while keeping the rest of the data.frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to use dplyr to apply a function to a subset of columns. However, in contrast to the code per below, I am trying to implement this while keeping all columns in the data-frame. Currently, the resulting data-frame only keeps the selected columns. I can use a remove-and-cbind construction to merge these columns back into the original dataframe, but I was wondering if there is a way to do this directly in dplyr? I have tried to move the select function inside the mutate function, but was not able to make this work yet.

```
require(dplyr)
Replace15=function(x){ifelse(x<1.5,1,x)}
dg <- iris %>%
  dplyr::select(starts_with("Petal")) %>%
  mutate_each(funs(Replace15))  
dg

> dg
Source: local data frame [150 x 2]

   Petal.Length Petal.Width
1           1.0           1
2           1.0           1
3           1.0           1
4           1.5           1
5           1.0           1
6           1.7           1
7           1.0           1
8           1.5           1
9           1.0           1
10          1.5           1
```

Comment: Maybe just `iris %>% mutate_each(funs(Replace15), starts_with("Petal")) `?

Comment: You can also define your function in terms of the built-in `replace` function. `ifelse` can be slow, if that's a concern of yours. http://stackoverflow.com/q/16275149/1191259

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dg <- iris %>% mutate_each(funs(Replace15), matches("^Petal"))
```

Alternatively (as posted by @aosmith) you could use `starts_with`. Have a look at `?select` for the other special functions available within `select`, `summarise_each` and `mutate_each.`

Answer (score 3):

[`mutate_each` is now deprecated](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise_each.html), replaced by `mutate_if` and `mutate_at`.  Using these replacements, the answer is

```
dg <- iris %>% mutate_at(vars(starts_with("Petal")), funs(Replace15))
```