# `print` function in `ifelse`

Tags: r, if-statement

I'm wondering why `ifelse(1<2,print("true"),print("false"))` returns

```
[1] "true"
[1] "true"
```

whereas `ifelse(1<2,"true","false")` returns

```
[1] "true"
```

I don't understand why the `print` within `ifelse` returns `"true"` twice

Comment: Probably related to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16275149/does-ifelse-really-calculate-both-of-its-vectors-every-time-is-it-slow/16275201#16275201).

Comment: also note that `ifelse` is really designed to be applied to vectors, not scalars, so perhaps you're better off using `if (1<2) print("true") else print("false")` anyway.

Comment: And note that if you assign it, like `z <- ifelse(1 < 2, print("true"), print("false"))`, the new object will hold the correct result.

Comment: An ancient tale says that every time a non-programmer dude says the word **bug** a programmer die. You have to clap your hands to make him live again.

Comment: `ifelse(1 < 2, print(print("true")), print("false"))` is another way to get a good look at what is happening.  Then reverse the operator.

Answer (score 14):

This happens because `ifelse` will always return a value. When you run `ifelse(1<2,print("true"),print("false"))`, your `yes` condition is chosen. This condition is a function call to print `"true"` on the console, and so it does.

But the `print()` function also returns its argument, but invisibly (like assignments, for example), otherwise you'd have the value printed twice in some cases. When the `yes` expression is evaluated, its result is what `ifelse` returns, and `ifelse` does not returns invisibly, so, it prints the result, since that was ran on the Global Environment and without any assignment.

We can test some variations and check what's going on.

```
> result <- print("true")
[1] "true" # Prints because the print() function was called.
> result
[1] "true" # The print function return its argument, which was assigned to the variable.

> ifelse(1<2, {print("true");"TRUE"},print("false"))
[1] "true" #This was printed because print() was called
[1] "TRUE" #This was printed because it was the value returned from the yes argument
```

If we assign this `ifelse()`

```
> result <- ifelse(1<2, {print("true");"TRUE"},print("false"))
[1] "true"
> result
[1] "TRUE"
```

We can also look at the case where both conditions conditions are evaluated:

```
> ifelse(c(1,3)<2, {print("true");"TRUE"},{print("false");"FALSE"})
[1] "true" # The yes argument prints this
[1] "false" # The no argument prints this
[1] "TRUE"  "FALSE" # This is the returned output from ifelse()
```

You should use `ifelse` to create a new object, not to perform actions based on a condition. For that, use `if` `else`. [The R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) has good section (3.2) on the difference between the two.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add some arguments to the excellent answer of Molx.
One of the reason why that happens relies on this:

```
length(print("true"))
[1] "true"
[1] 1
length(length(print("true")))
[1] "true"
[1] 1
length(length(length(print("true"))))
[1] "true"
[1] 1
```

... and so on...

In the R manual is stated that:

> yes   return values for true elements of test

note the **values**, and not **value**, here we have two values : one is the object of the print function (that has to print "true", most likely it is a call to a function, in this case `print`, that has as a result a character vector with `true`) and another one is the output print "true" which is the proper element of the `ifelse` statement.

It could be avoided with just:

```
 ifelse(1 < 2, "true" , "false" )
[1] "true"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the down vote. As always never a comment follow a down vote.

Comment: This part is not correct: *here we have two values: one is the object of the print function (that has to print "true") and another one is to print "true".* What you have there are two different vectors, one element each, the second one is the **only** result from `ifelse()`.  The first is only the result of `print()`, and is not part of the result of `ifelse()` at all.

Comment: @RichardScriven I have edited the question, now I think it is more clear. Our idea is the same maybe I did not write it clear. I know that now it is clear.

Answer (score -1):

Isn't it printing TRUE and returning TRUE at the same time?

So for example using cat instead of print would change the output...

This is basically related to ulfelders comment.

Comment: mmm use `cat` will throw an error message and a warning because it interprets its argument; try `ifelse(1<2, cat("true"), cat("false"))`.