# Add new column and assign values

Tags: r

I have a data frame df1 such that:

```
group=c(0,5,3,0,5,3)
year=c("2001","2002","2003", "2010", "2012", "2013")
items=c(12, 10, 15, 5, 10, 7)
df1=data.frame(group, year, items)
```

I want to create a new column where I assign a value to one year and while leaving the rest at 0. For example, I want it to look like this:

```
  group year items new  
1     0 2001    12   1
2     5 2002    10   0  
3     3 2003    15   0
4     0 2010     5   0
5     5 2012    10   0
6     3 2013     7   0
```

Thanks!

Comment: What are you really trying to achieve here?

Comment: The only reason I can see behind wanting to do that would be as an indicator. And I don't think you need that in R.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the absence of other requirements, I would use:

```
df1$new <- ifelse(year == 2001, 1, 0)
```

Comment: @akrun You should have kept that as an answer, it's pretty clever.

Comment: Indeed it is.  I'd like to see that as an answer and why it works.  I've never seen it before.

Comment: [_caveat emptor_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16275149/does-ifelse-really-calculate-both-of-its-vectors-every-time-is-it-slow) for all new `R` users considering an `ifelse` solution.

Comment: It is just one of the ways like `(year==2001)+0L` or `(year==2001)*1L` to coerce to integer.  But, I think it should be faster than the other ways.  I had seen @Frank using this kind of code golfing.

Comment: I have tried only for logical to binary conversion.  Do you have any specific example where it should be applied?

Comment: Not really. I was just trying to understand it. If I can find documentation for this behavior that'd be awesome. I guess it's time to actually read the ?'+' docs

Comment: "Unary + and unary - return a numeric or complex vector. All attributes (including class) are preserved if there is no coercion: logical x is coerced to integer and names, dims and dimnames are preserved."  Looks like it will work for anything that has a valid unary `+` method...the primary examples being numerical and logical.

Answer (score 4):

Just do

```
 df1$new <- +(df1$year==2001)
```