# Can you use a data.frame twice in a dplyr chain? dplyr says " Error: cannot handle "

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to use a data.frame twice in a `dplyr` chain.   Here is a simple example that gives an error

```
df <- data.frame(Value=1:10,Type=rep(c("A","B"),5))

df %>% 
  group_by(Type) %>% 
  summarize(X=n())  %>% 
  mutate(df %>%filter(Value>2) %>%  
  group_by(Type) %>%  
  summarize(Y=sum(Value)))

Error: cannot handle
```

So the idea is that first a `data.frame` is created with two columns `Value` which is just some data and `Type` which indicates which group the value is from.

I then try to use summarize to get the number of objects in each group, and then mutate, using the object again to get the sum of the values, after the data has been filtered.  However I get the `Error: cannot handle`. Any ideas what is happening here?

**Desired Output:**

```
Type X Y
  A  5 24
  B  5 28
```

Comment: @DavidArenburg Desired output added. At least dplyr is being honest when it is overwhelmed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try the following

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Type) %>% 
  summarise(X = n(), Y = sum(Value[Value > 2]))

# Source: local data frame [2 x 3]
# 
#   Type X  Y
# 1    A 5 24
# 2    B 5 28
```

The idea is to filter only `Value` by the desired condition, instead the whole data set

---

And a bonus solution

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(X = .N, Y = sum(Value[Value > 2])), by = Type]
#    Type X  Y
# 1:    A 5 24
# 2:    B 5 28
```

---

Was going to suggest that to @nongkrong but he deleted, with base R we could also do

```
aggregate(Value ~ Type, df, function(x) c(length(x), sum(x[x>2])))
#   Type Value.1 Value.2
# 1    A       5      24
# 2    B       5      28
```

Comment: Thanks. I went the `ifelse` route just because my actual conditions were more complex and I found the code easier to understand, but your multiple solutions are very informative.

Comment: That's fine, though `ifelse` is usually not very efficient for big data sets. Most of the problem can be solved without it (from my experience at least)

Comment: Jumping on David's comment, I totally agree. For big datasets, I prefer `data.table`, although even there I run into some long vector issues with reshaping.

Comment: @bjoseph it's not about `data.table` vs `dplyr` rather just `ifelse`. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16275149/does-ifelse-really-calculate-both-of-its-vectors-every-time-is-it-slow)

Comment: @bjoseph You folks convinced me - I rewrote and removed the `ifelse` , I should learn not to be lazy

Answer (score 3):

This is also pretty easy to do with `ifelse()`

```
df %>% group_by(Type) %>% summarize(X=n(),y=sum( ifelse(Value>2, Value, 0 )))
```

outputs:

```
Source: local data frame [2 x 3]

  Type X  y
1    A 5 24
2    B 5 28
```

Comment: This worked great - my actual problem had somewhat more complicated conditions and this was easier to adapt for me.

Comment: I find `dplyr` syntax confusing too, and I make extensive use of `ifelse` inside `dplyr` statements. It works in a surprising amount of cases.