# Optimizing ifelse on a large data frame

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe, subset, splunk

I have a data frame **df** that looks like this:

```
A B C 
1 2 3
2 5 6
3 8 9
```

the below line of code adds a new column and fills data accordingly.

```
df$Mean.Result1 <- ifelse(df[, "A"] > 0.05 & df[, "B"] > 0.05, "Equal", "")
```

I am using ***R with Splunk***, and **R** in **Splunk** is not able to recognize the above format.

Is it right to do:

```
df.$Mean.Result1 <- ifelse(df.$A > 0.05 & df$B > 0.05, "Equal", "")
```

How are the two pieces of code different? Will it affect the the speed of computation? My actual dataset has around 500 million rows and 400 columns.

Comment: If you have 500 million rows it would be _much, much_ more efficient, both memory-wise and computation-wise, to do `df.$Mean.Result1 <- ifelse(df.$A > 0.05 & df.$B > 0.05, 1L, 0L)` and then `df.$Mean.Result1 <- factor(df.$Mean.Result1, levels=c(1L, 0L), labels=c("Equal", ""))`. You will reduce the size of your table drastically and all operations involving `df.$Mean.Result1` will be _much_ faster. Avoid strings as much as you can, R does not handle them efficiently.

Comment: `df[, "A"]` is equivalent to `df$A`, not `df.$A`. The two pieces of code are different because one use variable `df` and the other `df.`. Using the first or the second form is strictly equivalent in terms of computation cost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There [has been some discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16275149/does-ifelse-really-calculate-both-of-its-vectors-every-time-is-it-slow) about how `ifelse` is not the best option for code where speed is an important factor. You might instead try:

```
df$Mean.Result1 <- c("", "Equal")[(df$A > 0.05 & df$B > 0.05)+1]
```

To see what's going on here, let's break down the command. `df$A > 0.05 & df$B > 0.05` returns `TRUE` if both `A` and `B` exceed 0.05, and `FALSE` otherwise. Therefore, `(df$A > 0.05 & df$B > 0.05)+1` returns 2 if both `A` and `B` exceed  0.05 and 1 otherwise. These are used as indicates into the vector `c("", "Equal")`, so we get `"Equal"` when both exceed 0.05 and `""` otherwise.

Here's a comparison on a data frame with 1 million rows:

```
# Build dataset and functions
set.seed(144)
big.df <- data.frame(A = runif(1000000), B = runif(1000000))
OP <- function(df) {
  df$Mean.Result1 <- ifelse(df$A > 0.05 & df$B > 0.05, "Equal", "")
  df
}
josilber <- function(df) {
  df$Mean.Result1 <- c("", "Equal")[(df$A > 0.05 & df$B > 0.05)+1]
  df
}
all.equal(OP(big.df), josilber(big.df))
# [1] TRUE

# Benchmark
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(OP(big.df), josilber(big.df))
# Unit: milliseconds
#              expr      min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval
#        OP(big.df) 299.6265 311.56167 352.26841 318.51825 348.09461 540.0971   100
#  josilber(big.df)  40.4256  48.66967  60.72864  53.18471  59.72079 267.3886   100
```

The approach with vector indexing is about 6x faster in median runtime.

Comment: thanks for the quick and crisp explanation, it is really really helpful.

Comment: @josilber, very clever!

Comment: Very nice. @kRazzyR If memory is an issue, consider casting to factor, you will cut the size of the object by half.

Comment: @josilber ,could be kind enough to explain the line of code `df$Mean.Result1 <- c("", "Equal")[(df$A > 0.05 & df$B > 0.05)+1]`

Comment: @kRazzyR I've added a paragraph of explanation

Comment: @josilber thanks.  Based on what you have explained I have tried this `set.seed(144)
big.df <- data.frame(A = runif(1000000), B = runif(1000000))
OP <- function(df) {
  df$Mean.Result1 <- ifelse(df$A > 0.05 & df$B > 0.05, "Equal", "")
  df
}
abc <- function(df) {
  
  if(df$A>0.05 && df$B>0.05)
 
     {  df$Mean.Result1<-"Equal" 
  }else
    { df$Mean.Result1<-""
  }
  df
}
all.equal(OP(big.df), abc(big.df))


# Benchmark
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(OP(big.df), abc(big.df))
`

Comment: though I get the results of the microbenchmark as 

*Unit: milliseconds
        expr        min        lq      mean   median        uq      max neval cld
  OP(big.df) 441.378891 471.13532 538.02689 481.7621 495.85562 3191.401   100   b
 abc(big.df)   9.891185  12.59788  42.31095  14.8395  15.16461 2738.666   100  a *

After the line `all.equal . . .`  R outputs   *"Component “Mean.Result1”: 902737 string mismatches"* what does it mean how do I resolve it?