# Multiple conditions for ifelse

Tags: r, if-statement

I'm trying to create a variable (df$check6) that has a 1 if ANY of the following are true using the following code:

```
df$check  <- ifelse(df$var1 == 1 & df$var2 == 1, 1,0)
df$check2 <- ifelse(df$var3 == 1 & df$var4 == 1, 1,0) 
df$check3 <- ifelse(df$var5 == 1 & df$var6 == 1, 1, 0) 
df$check4 <- ifelse(df$var7 >=4 & df$var8 == 1, 1,0) 
df$check5 <- ifelse(df$var9 >=4 & df$var10 == 1, 1,0)

df$check6 <- ifelse(df$check== 1 | df$check2 == 1 | df$check3 == 1 | df$check4 == 1, df$check5 == 1, 1,0)
```

When I run the code, my df$var7 and df$var9 are all changed to 1 when they were originally a "." in my dataset. My >=4 condition does also not appear to be working. My df$check6 = 1 when those 2 variables are numeric values of "2", when the condition is that they should be equal to or greater than 4.

I know there must be a simpler way to do this but I just tried to use the basics. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

EDIT: 
var 1, 3, 5 were stored as either 1, 0 or "."
I created a subset that only included values that were == 1 (excluding 0 and "." cases)

Converted var 1-6,8,10 to logical, as suggested 
7,9 were numeric

Answer provided then worked perfectly on my dataset.

Comment: Could you please provide a data frame `df` that demonstrates why the provided code is not working for you? You can read more about how to provide a reproducible example at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: If something is == "." then it's  probably factor. Factors do not respond to tests regarding order.

Answer (score 2):

I find the syntax for this much easier to comprehend in `data.table` (in addition to the other advantages provided by `data.table`). It will also be easier if the variables you're comparing to 1 are stored as logical (as it seems they should be):

```
library(data.table)
#convert df to a 'data.table' by reference
setDT(df)

df[ , check6 := (var1 & var2) | (var3 & var4) |
      (var5 & var6) | (var7 >= 4 & var8) | (var9 >=4 & var10)]
```

If `var`s 1,2,3,4,5,6,8,10 are not already stored as logical, and they take values outside 0,1, you can quickly convert them all to logical with:

```
lgkls <- paste0("var", c(1:6, 8 , 10))
df[ , (lgkls) := lapply(.SD, function(x) x == 1), .SDcols = lgkls]
```

If you really need the intermediate check variables, you could do:

```
df[ , check1 := var1 & var2]
df[ , check2 := var3 & var4]
df[ , check3 := var5 & var6]
df[ , check4 := var7 >= 4 & var8]
df[ , check5 := var9 >= 4 & var10]
df[ , check6 := check1 | check2 | check3 | check4 | check5]
```

And of course if you really need `check6` to be stored as an `integer` (doubtful), you can add the "cheater"'s converter:

```
df[ , check6 := +(check1 | check2 | check3 | check4 | check5)]
```

See [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki) for more about `data.table` & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16275149/does-ifelse-really-calculate-both-of-its-vectors-every-time-is-it-slow) for why it's good practice to avoid `ifelse` as much as possible.

Comment: Are var1-6, 8, and 10 exclusively 1 or 0 though? Because it seems like they are looking for values exactly equal to 1, not non-zero values.

Comment: @bramtayl I got the feeling they were probably stored as 1,0, but of course it's easy to convert them to `logical`s; see edit

Comment: @bramtayl var 2,4,6,10 are exclusively 1 or 0. Var 1,3,5 can be 1, 0 or "."

Comment: If the dots came in from reading a csv, you might want to add an extra argument: `read.csv(na.strings = ".")` This will read in your variables as numeric which will be useful

Comment: @MichaelChirico I converted var 1-6, 8,10 as logical using as.logical( ) and 7, 9 are numeric. Running the above code^ I get "NA" for check2 when var3 & var 4 are = 1, or when var4 = 1 and var3 = ".", or when var4 = 1 and var 3 = 0.   Could this be because my var 1,3,5 can be stored as '1, 0 or "."' ?

Comment: @Prccrt I can't know that without a reproducible example, but I feel like BondedDust's comment is probably accurate.

Comment: @MichaelChirico Thanks for all the help. Sorry I couldn't make a reproducible sample for you (still working on figuring that out so I can make it easier to get help in the future). I figured out something that seems to work with my dataset and applied your code and it worked! Going to update my question above.