# Maximum value of one data.table column based on other columns

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `R` `data.table`

```
DT = data.table(x=rep(c("b","a",NA_character_),each=3), y=rep(c('A', NA_character_, 'C'), each=3), z=c(NA_character_), v=1:9) 
DT
#    x  y  z v
#1:  b  A NA 1
#2:  b  A NA 2
#3:  b  A NA 3
#4:  a NA NA 4
#5:  a NA NA 5
#6:  a NA NA 6
#7: NA  C NA 7
#8: NA  C NA 8
#9: NA  C NA 9
```

For each column if the value is not `NA`, I want to extract the max value from column `v`. I am using

```
sapply(DT, function(x) { ifelse(all(is.na(x)), NA_integer_, max(DT[['v']][!is.na(x)])) })
 #x  y  z  v 
 #6  9 NA  9
```

Is there a simpler way to achive this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is a way, giving you `-Inf` (and a warning) if all values of the column are `NA` (you can later replace that by `NA` if you prefer):

```
DT[, lapply(.SD, function(x) max(v[!is.na(x)]))]
#    x y    z v
# 1: 6 9 -Inf 9
```

As suggested by @DavidArenburg, to ensure that everything goes well even when all values are `NA` (no warning and directly `NA` as result), you can do:

```
DT[, lapply(.SD, function(x) {
  temp <- v[!is.na(x)] 
  if(!length(temp)) NA else max(temp)
})]
#   x y  z v
#1: 6 9 NA 9
```

Comment: thanks @DavidArenburg and thanks for the more robust way, I'll add that!

Comment: Thanks. But is't it same as what I have got now.

Comment: There is also the `na.rm` argument of `max` (which is faster than subsetting and taking the max).

Comment: `na.rm` removes `na` but doesn't returns `na` if all the columns are `na`.

Comment: @imsc this is very different from your answer. 1- You are using `sapply` externally of the `DT`s scope and thus it's not optimized. 2- Unnecessary use of `ifelse` which can be very dangerous sometimes. 3- You code ins't concise. While this solution is pretty much the idiomatic `data.table` way, although there could be probably some more code golfing that can be done.

Comment: Thanks @DavidArenburg for the explanation. On a different note, why is `ifelse` dangerous?

Comment: `ifelse` has various side effects, here's one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6668963/how-to-prevent-ifelse-from-turning-date-objects-into-numeric-objects it also not so efficient in general http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16275149/does-ifelse-really-calculate-both-of-its-vectors-every-time-is-it-slow

Answer (score 1):

We can use `summarise_each` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
DT %>%
   summarise_each(funs(max(v[!is.na(.)])))
#    x y    z v
#1: 6 9 -Inf 9
```

Comment: NOTE: I would be happy to use `%>%` and have the rest in 2 lines instead of cramming everything in a line and call it as a `one-liner`