# R help:if else loop by id

Tags: r

Please modify below code by loan id in R for below data

```
id     no_of_months   reminder
1        2              16
2        2              15
3        3              15
4        2              12
5        2              14
```

I want to apply below formula in 3rd column as `no_of_months`.

```
if(reminder > 0 & reminder < 15){
        no_of_months= no_of_months - 1
}
else{
        no_of_months
}
```

Comment: `ifelse(df$reminder > 0 & df$reminder < 15, df$no_of_months - 1 , df$no_of_months )`

Comment: Many Thanks for this!!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I interpret your question correctly, you want to create a third column that satisfies that equality.

You can use `ifelse` as Ronak has shown, but in keeping with `for`-loop form, you might want to try something like:

```
df <- data.frame("no_of_months" = c(2, 2, 3, 2, 2),
                 "reminder" = c(16, 15, 15, 12, 14))

for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  if(df$reminder[i] > 0 & df$reminder[i] < 15){
        df$newColumn[i] <- df$no_of_months[i] - 1
  }else{
        df$newColumn[i] <- df$no_of_months[i]
  }
}
```

In this loop, we use `$` to index a column of a `data.frame` by name. By indexing an unnamed column, we create a column. Then, we use `i` to index the entry in that column (equivalent to row).

Comment: @Sobana This loop is slow compared to the vectorized solution.

Comment: @Roland It's a bit more complicated than that (link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34005423/is-if-faster-than-ifelse). Also, IMHO, relying on ifelse teaches bad fundamentals ;)

Comment: Looping over the rows of a data.frame is not a fundamental in R. Vectorization is.