# how ifelse (in data.table) works

Tags: r, data.table

In my `data.table`, I wanted to numerate entries if there are more than one in each `by` group:

```
dt1 <- data.table(col1=1:4, col2 = c('A', 'B', 'B', 'C'))
#    col1 col2
# 1:    1    A
# 2:    2    B
# 3:    3    B
# 4:    4    C

dt1[, col3:={
  if (.N>1) {paste0((1:.N), "_", col2)} else {col2};
}, by=col2]

#    col1 col2 col3
# 1:    1    A    A
# 2:    2    B  1_B
# 3:    3    B  2_B
# 4:    4    C    C
```

This works fine, but didn't work when I tried to use `ifelse()` instead:

```
dt1[, col4:=ifelse (.N>1, paste0((1:.N), "_", col2), col2), by=col2]
#    col1 col2 col3 col4
# 1:    1    A    A    A
# 2:    2    B  1_B  1_B
# 3:    3    B  2_B  1_B
# 4:    4    C    C    C
```

can anyone explain why?

Comment: `ifelse` returns one value for each test. You wanted more than one. It is only returning `1_B` as it was built to.

Comment: @PierreLafortune, thanks, it seems to be indeed a duplicate of that question. I just expected that "one value" could be one vector value as well. Current behavior looks rather cont-intuituve for me, but OK

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is only by proxy related to `data.table`; at core is that `ifelse` is designed for use like:

```
ifelse(test, yes, no)
```

where `test`, `yes`, and `no` all have *the same length* -- the output will be the same length as `test`, and all the elements corresponding to where `test` is `TRUE` will be the corresponding element from `yes`, and similarly for where `test` is `FALSE`.

When `test` is a scalar and `yes` or `no` are vectors, as in your case, you have to look at what `ifelse` is doing to understand what's going on:

Relevant source:

```
if (any(test[ok])) #is any element of `test` `TRUE`?
        ans[test & ok] <- rep(yes, length.out = length(ans))[test & 
            ok]
```

What is `rep(c(1, 2), length.out = 1)`? It's just `1` -- the second element is truncated.

That's what's happened here -- the value of `ifelse` is only the first element of `paste0(1:.N, "_", col2)`. When passed to `` `:=` ``, this single element is recycled.

When your logical condition is a scalar, you should use `if`, not `ifelse`. I'll also add that I do my damndest to avoid using `ifelse` in general because [it's slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16275149/does-ifelse-really-calculate-both-of-its-vectors-every-time-is-it-slow).