# Is ifelse() in R efficient for determining which function to call on a large vector?

Tags: r, performance, if-statement

I'm currently writing a code that will call a specific function, depending on the value of an element in a vector. My question, then, is whether or not this is efficient. If I understand the `ifelse` algorithm correctly, whatever values I put as the 2nd and 3rd arguments to the function are calculated in their entirety and then subsetted based on the `TRUE` or `FALSE` values of my condition. This is in contrast to the typical `if/else` structure we see in coding, where we'd evaluate a condition and then run a function on the element only once we know which function to run. To test this out, I tried to use the following:

```
test1 <- function() {
  x <- sample(1:1e9, 1e6, replace = TRUE)
  y <- ifelse(x %% 2 == 0, x**2, x/2)
  return(y)
}

test2 <- function() {
  x <- sample(1:1e9, 1e6, replace = TRUE)
  y <- numeric(length(x))
  for (i in 1:length(x)) {
    if (x[i] %% 2 == 0) {
      y[i] <- x[i]**2
    } else {
      y[i] <- x[i]/2
    }
  }
  return(y)
}
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(test1(), test2(), times = 1000)

Unit: milliseconds
    expr       min        lq     mean    median        uq      max neval
 test1()  2.366067  2.494746  8.27343  2.580164  2.706826 1690.049  1000
 test2() 21.773385 23.050818 29.70450 23.712907 29.468783 3169.008  1000
```

The mean values seem to indicate that the `ifelse` approach is favorable over `if/else`.

The reason I'm asking is because I'll have relatively large XML files that I'm parsing and the parsing methods I implement will vary depending on the layout of the children in the tree and I'm trying to be as efficient as possible.

So two questions: 1) Are my conclusions above correct, that `ifelse` is faster than `if/else`, and 2) does `ifelse` calculate all values for both `yes` and `no` vectors and then subset them?

Thanks in advance.

### Edit

The code above, as well as some of the question text, has been modified to reflect the comments below.

Comment: `ifelse` has a whole bunch of checking of inputs etc that your `test2` function does not have. This probably accounts for most of the nanoseconds of difference. The core of `ifelse` is essentially an `if/else` the same as what you have + some adjustment for `NA` values.

Comment: Your `test2` has an error in it; try running it by itself. Also your benchmark command should call `test1()` and `test2()`, otherwise it's not actually running the code.

Comment: And if you really want to see the performance difference, pre-simulate `x` and pass it in to your functions.

Comment: @aaron Good call! I'll update the question to reflect that.

Comment: You should find that `ifelse` is substantially faster for this example.

Comment: @Aaron Yeah, that's what I just found. Had I actually formatted my reproducible example correctly, this question probably wouldn't have even been asked. I'll be deleting it since there's no longer a real question here.

Comment: In response to 2), according to the help file, "yes will be evaluated if and only if any element of test is true, and analogously for no," so the answer is yes except for the case where one is never needed.

Comment: Also see the suggestions in the help file under the `Warning` section that give an example of a type of construction that might be preferred.

Comment: @gregor I don't necessarily have a question anymore, but SO wouldn't let me delete the question because it had an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you've coded does worse than `ifelse`, but as suggested in the *warning* section of `?ifelse` it's possible to do better. With your simple functions, `x^2` and `x / 2`, the `test3()` function below  is faster - about 2 to 3 times faster than `ifelse` and 30 times faster than `test2()`. With more computationally intensive functions (but still vectorized!) the margin might be bigger.

The speed gain is (I think) mostly due to two sources:

1. `ifelse` does input checking and error handling that `test3()` skips. `ifelse` is more general and more flexible... `test3()` is hardcoded to only return a `numeric` vector).
2. As demonstrated at [Does ifelse really calculate both of its vectors every time? Is it slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16275149/903061), `ifelse` will calculate its entire `TRUE` response vector as long as there is at least 1 `TRUE` value of the test, and similarly for its `FALSE`. `test3()` bypasses the extra calculations by creating `TRUE` and `FALSE` sub-vectors.

---

I've modified your `test1()` and `test2()` to simplify a bit, pulling out the data simulation (since that's not what we want to test). I added `test3` that uses logical subsets. I also drastically reduced the size of the test vector so it runs reasonably quickly.

```
set.seed(47)
x <- sample(1:1e6, 1e4, replace = TRUE)

test1 <- function(x) {
  ifelse(x %% 2 == 0, x**2, x/2)
}

test2 <- function(x) {
  y <- numeric(length(x))
  for (i in seq_along(x)) {
    if (x[i] %% 2 == 0) {
      y[i] <- x[i]**2
    } else {
      y[i] <- x[i]/2
    }
  }
  return(y)
}

test3 <- function(x) {
    y = numeric(length(x))
    cond = x %% 2 == 0
    y[cond] = x[cond] ^ 2
    y[!cond] = x[!cond] / 2
    return(y)
}

identical(test1(x), test2(x))
# TRUE
identical(test1(x), test3(x))
# TRUE
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(test1(x), test2(x), test3(x), times = 1000)
# Unit: microseconds
#      expr       min         lq       mean     median        uq        max neval cld
#  test1(x)  1563.270  1642.3540  1701.3877  1669.2180  1697.894   3159.743  1000  b 
#  test2(x) 17909.833 18788.9635 23682.1516 19882.8600 20679.436 116206.536  1000   c
#  test3(x)   627.241   668.7445   691.8433   680.6675   696.061   1340.507  1000 a
```

Comment: It seems as if the answer is that `ifelse` is much faster than `if/else`, but code can typically be rewritten in a way that is even faster than `ifelse`, which makes total sense to me. Thanks!