# Plot conditional colors based on rows

Tags: r, plot, colors

I have two data.frames called **outlier** and **data**.

**outlier** just keeps row numbers which needs to be coloured. 
**data** has 1000 data.
It has two columns called **x** and **y**.
If row number exists in outliers I want dots in plot to be **red**, otherwise **black**

```
plot(data$x, data$y, col=ifelse(??,"red","black"))
```

Something should be in ?? .

Comment: ?? should be `1:lenght(x) %in% outlier`

Comment: how did you create `outlier` in the first place...

Comment: long story short, if I print `outlier .[1] 178 318 333 556 611 615 716 840 965`

Comment: I don't know why you need how I created outliers. But in case. `outliers = which( data$x > (quantile(data$x,0.5) +IQR) )`

Comment: `quantile(data$x,0.5) == median(data$x)`

Comment: Unless you need it for something else, skip creating `outlier`: `plot(x, y, col = ifelse( x > ..., "red", "black"))`. Better yet [skip `ifelse`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16275149/does-ifelse-really-calculate-both-of-its-vectors-every-time-is-it-slow) by doing: `c("black", "red")[(x > ...) + 1L]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi this way works for me using `ifelse`, let me know what you think:

```
outlier <- sample(1:100, 50)
data <- data.frame(x = 1:100, y = rnorm(n = 100))
plot(
  data[ ,1], data[ ,2]
  ,col = ifelse(row.names(data) %in% outlier, "red", "blue")
  ,type = "h"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be accomplished by creating a new color column in your data frame:

```
data$color <- "black"
```

Then set the outliers to a different value:

```
data[outlier,"color"] <- "red"
```

I dont have your exact data but I think I got something similar to what you wanted using the following:

```
outlier <- c(1, 2, 7, 9)
data <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
                   y=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10))
data$color <- "black"
data[outlier,"color"] <- "red"
data
    x  y color
1   1  1   red
2   2  2   red
3   3  3 black
4   4  4 black
5   5  5 black
6   6  6 black
7   7  7   red
8   8  8 black
9   9  9   red
10 10 10 black
```

Finally plot using the new value in data:

```
plot(data$x, data$y, col=data$color)
```

Results in:[image: the following chart]

Comment: It produces right colors, but it is a little bit longer. I would like ot achieve it by `ifelse` or simpler version. Again, yes it works. Thanks for you time

Comment: Hi Etibar, I am a little confused by your comment.  My solution is 2 lines.  Are you saying you will only accept an answer that is 0 or 1 lines in length?