# Using dplyr to conditionally replace values in a column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have an example data set with a column that reads somewhat like this:

```
Candy
Sanitizer
Candy
Water
Cake
Candy
Ice Cream
Gum
Candy
Coffee
```

What I'd like to do is replace it into just two factors - "Candy" and "Non-Candy". I can do this with Python/Pandas, but can't seem to figure out a dplyr based solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Assuming your data frame is `dat` and your column is `var`:

```
dat = dat %>% mutate(candy.flag = factor(ifelse(var == "Candy", "Candy", "Non-Candy")))
```

Comment: @RichardScriven's approach (comments on mine) strictly dominates this

Answer (score 93):

In `dplyr` and `tidyr`

```
dat %>% 
    mutate(var = replace(var, var != "Candy", "Not Candy"))
```

Significantly faster than the `ifelse` approaches.
Code to create the initial dataframe can be as below:

```
library(dplyr)
dat <- as_data_frame(c("Candy","Sanitizer","Candy","Water","Cake","Candy","Ice Cream","Gum","Candy","Coffee"))
colnames(dat) <- "var"
```

Comment: Isn't there a function that does not require to repeat `var`?

Comment: The only function that I am familiar with that autopopulates the conditional statement is [replace_na()](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/replace_na.html)
explanation: The first `var` refs the output name you want. The second `var` the input column and the third `var` specifies the column to use in the conditional statement you are applying. A function missing one of these would have to assume (hard-code in) one or more of these [input, output, conditional column].

Answer (score 23):

Another solution with `dplyr` using `case_when`:

```
dat %>%
    mutate(var = case_when(var == 'Candy' ~ 'Candy',
                           TRUE ~ 'Non-Candy'))
```

The syntax for `case_when` is `condition ~ value to replace`. Documentation [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html).

Probably less efficient than the solution using `replace`, but an advantage is that multiple replacements could be performed in a single command while still being nicely readable, i.e. replacing to produce three levels:

```
dat %>%
    mutate(var = case_when(var == 'Candy' ~ 'Candy',
                           var == 'Water' ~ 'Water',
                           TRUE ~ 'Neither-Water-Nor-Candy'))
```

Answer (score 9):

No need for `dplyr`. Assuming `var` is stored as a factor already:

```r
non_c <- setdiff(levels(dat$var), "Candy")
    
levels(dat$var) <- list(Candy = "Candy", "Non-Candy" = non_c)
```

See `?levels`.

This is *much* more efficient than the `ifelse` approach, which is [bound to be slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16275149/does-ifelse-really-calculate-both-of-its-vectors-every-time-is-it-slow):

```r
library(microbenchmark)
set.seed(01239)
# resample data
smp <- data.frame(sample(dat$var, 1e6, TRUE))
names(smp) <- "var"
    
timings <- replicate(50, {
  # copy data to facilitate reuse
  cop <- smp
  t0 <- get_nanotime()
  levs <- setdiff(levels(cop$var), "Candy")
  levels(cop$var) <- list(Candy = "Candy", "Non-Candy" = levs)
  t1 <- get_nanotime() - t0

  cop <- smp
  t0 <- get_nanotime()
  cop = cop %>%
    mutate(candy.flag = factor(ifelse(var == "Candy", "Candy", "Non-Candy")))
  t2 <- get_nanotime() - t0

  cop <- smp
  t0 <- get_nanotime()
  cop$var <- 
    factor(cop$var == "Candy", labels = c("Non-Candy", "Candy"))
  t3 <- get_nanotime() - t0
  c(levels = t1, dplyr = t2, direct = t3)
})

x <- apply(times, 1, median)
x[2]/x[1]
#    dplyr   direct 
# 8.894303 4.962791
```

That is, this is 9 times faster.

Comment: Or also `factor(dat$var == "Candy", labels = c("Non-Candy", "Candy"))`  but I think resetting the levels is a nice way to go.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't benchmark this, but at least in some cases with more than one condition, a combination of *mutate* and a list seems to provide an easy solution:

```
# assuming that all sweet things fall in one category

dat <- data.frame(var = c("Candy", "Sanitizer", "Candy", "Water", "Cake", "Candy", "Ice Cream", "Gum", "Candy", "Coffee"))

conditions <- list("Candy" = TRUE, "Sanitizer" = FALSE, "Water" = FALSE, 
"Cake" = TRUE, "Ice Cream" = TRUE, "Gum" = TRUE, "Coffee" = FALSE)

dat %>% mutate(sweet = conditions[var])
```

Comment: Way too long to write

Answer (score 2):

A newer solution is to use `case_match` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% 
    mutate(var = case_match(var, "Candy" ~ var, 
                           .default ~ "Not Candy"))
```

Answer (score 1):

When you only need two values, a simple ifelse() is prettiet, I think.

Furthermore, embedded ifelses can simulate the same situation as the case_when solution proposed by PhJ (I do like his readability, though)!

```
dat %>%
    mutate(
        var = ifelse(var == "Candy", "Candy", "Non-Candy")
    )
```