# Replace NAs according to conditions

Tags: r, if-statement, na

I have a dataset with lots of numerical variables, and a character variables that says whether or not low values are suppressed for that observation. In observations where values aren't suppressed, I want to replace NAs 0s (just for specific variables), and I can't figure it out. This is my data:

```
suppressed var1 var2
      none    2    6
      none   NA    6
      none    3    7
      none   NA   NA
      full    2    6
      full    3    6
      none    3   NA
      partial NA    6
      none    2    7
      none    NA   NA
```

What I want to do is change NA to 0 in Var 1, if Suppressed=none. I tried

```
df$Var1<-if (df$suppressed=='none'&is.na(df$Var1)) 0 
         else df$Var1
```

and got

```
Error in if (df$suppressed == "none" & is.na(df$Var1)) 0 else df$Var1 : 
  argument is of length zero
```

Is there something wrong with my if else statement, or is there another way to do this?

Here's the structure of my data:

```
structure(list(suppressed = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("full", "none", "partial"), class = "factor"), var1 = c(2, NA, 3, NA, 2, 3, 3, NA, 2, NA), var2 = c(6, 6, 7, NA, 6, 6, NA, 6, 7, NA)), .Names = c("suppressed", "var1", "var2"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Just do `df[df$suppressed == 'none'& is.na(df$var1), "var1"] <- 0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ifelse()` can do the trick.  It takes three arguments - the condition, the if output, and the else output.

```
df$Var1 <- ifelse(df$suppressed == 'none' & is.na(df$Var1), 0, Var1)
```

You don't have any curly brackets in your code {}.

```
if(df$suppressed == 'none' & is.na(df$Var1)){
    df$Var1 <- 0
   }else{
    df$Var1 <- df$Var1
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: There is absolutely no need in `ifelse` when you only have one condition to fulfill. Why would you need to put `Var1` into the *else* part if it is already there?

Comment: I totally agree, but seeing as how he was trying to use an if-statement, I wanted to show him ifelse().  But, I can't argue with you.

Comment: Also, `df$var1 == NA` isn't doing what you think it is doing. So your second option won't work.

Comment: Why doesn't it work?  It tests a logical condition, no?

Comment: No. R doesn't know if something is equals to `NA` or not because it doesn't know what's `NA` is equals to. This is why we have the `is.na` function. So anything that is being tested against `NA` will return `NA`. Try `c(1, NA, "h") == NA`, for instance. Or even just `NA == NA`. It is always better to test your code in general.

Comment: Thank you!  Learned something today.

Comment: Though I agree that your answer is useful for more general cases (+1). But here something else you might want to be aware of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16275149/does-ifelse-really-calculate-both-of-its-vectors-every-time-is-it-slow.