# undefined variable in unreached ifelse clause causes error

Tags: r, if-statement

I have two nested `ifelse` statements in a function.  When I call the function, it fails because a variable in the last `else` clause is undefined - even if that clause is not reached.

```
x <- factor(c("a", "b", "c", "d"))

h <- "hi"
l <- "lo"
```

Now undefined variable `m` is never used, but this produces an error:

```
ifelse(as.numeric(x) > 2, h,
       ifelse(as.numeric(x) < 3, l, m))
```

> Error in ifelse(as.numeric(x) < 3, l, m) : object 'm' not found

Even though all four values of `x` satisfy the first two `if` conditions:

```
> sum(as.numeric(x) > 2 | as.numeric(x) < 3)
[1] 4
```

Edit: I intentionally haven't defined `m` in this example, but I'd like to know how this is evaluated such that R looks for `m` when the last clause is never reached.

Comment: Yes.  But how does it evaluate the code to even look for `m`?  I'd expect that only to occur when the first two if conditions aren't met.  I've added that to the post.

Comment: Feel free to do something like `ifelse(as.numeric(x) < 3, l, NA)` rather than something that doesn't exist.

Comment: The "no" argument of `ifelse` will be evaluated if "test" argument has `FALSE` and `as.numeric(x) < 3` and `as.numeric(x) < 2` do; e.g. `ifelse(5 > 3:4, 1, "a" + "b")` and `ifelse(5 > 3:6, 1, "a" + "b")`

Comment: Deleted my earlier comment - it is possible to bypass `ifelse()`'s evaluation of  `no` if there are no no's in the input: `ifelse(1:3 < 100, 1:3, aksdjflaskj)` is fine. But `ifelse` deals in entire vectors and in your case `as.numeric(x)` **is** less than 3 in some cases as @alexis_laz points out. I'd actually be tempted to close as a dupe of [Does ifelse() really calculate both its vectors every time?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16275149/903061).

Comment: In your example, the inner `ifelse` is the `no` argument to the outer `ifelse` - and the argument needs to be evaluated. Nothing tells the inner `ifelse` call that only it's Yes indices are needed. It will try to produce an entire result vector and fail. The inner statement will need to be completely evaluated *before* the outer statement.