# R use ifelse to replicate

Tags: r, if-statement, data.table, data-manipulation, replicate

I want to use `ifelse` to replicate my data.
The problem is How to use `ifelse` to replicate different rows, which have different conditions.  Or maybe there are other solutions.
data here:

```
type     Time          value
A        2015-01-01    100
A        2016-05-01    200
B        2015-12-01    150
B        2016-12-01    300
```

The result I want is like:

```
type     Time          value
A        2015-01-01    100
A        2015-01-01    100
A        2015-01-01    100
A        2015-01-01    100
A        2015-01-01    100
A        2015-01-01    100
A        2015-01-01    100
A        2015-01-01    100
A        2015-01-01    100
A        2015-01-01    100
A        2015-01-01    100
A        2015-01-01    100
A        2015-01-01    100
A        2016-05-01    200
A        2016-05-01    200
A        2016-05-01    200
A        2016-05-01    200
A        2016-05-01    200
A        2016-05-01    200
A        2016-05-01    200
A        2016-05-01    200
B        2015-12-01    150
B        2015-12-01    150
B        2015-12-01    150
B        2015-12-01    150
B        2015-12-01    150
B        2015-12-01    150
B        2015-12-01    150
B        2015-12-01    150
B        2015-12-01    150
B        2015-12-01    150
B        2015-12-01    150
B        2015-12-01    150
B        2015-12-01    150    
B        2016-12-01    300
```

My code:

```
library(readxl)
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)
data <- read_excel("data.xlsx")
data <- as.data.table(data)
data[,Time:=as.Date(Time,"%Y/%m/%d")]
result <- data[ifelse(year(Time)==2016,rep(1:.N,12-month(Time)+1),rep(1:.N,13))]
```

However, it is not the same as what I actually want.
I think the problem is I cannot use `.N`. Any suggestion? 
Thanks.

Comment: Is `.N` a variable you've declared? Or a function? Try encasing `.N` in backwards apostophes. `\`.N\``

Comment: `.N` is a special-symbol in package `data.table`. use `?.N` for more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a `reps` column based on your conditions, that will allow us to repeat each row times the value in this new variable:

```
library(data.table)
data[,reps:=ifelse(year(Time)==2016, 12-month(Time)+1, 13)][rep(1:.N,reps)]
```

Or without `ifelse()`:

```
data[,reps := 13][year(Time)==2016, reps := 11-month(Time)][rep(1:.N, reps)]
```

Comment: Since ifelse is slow, maybe better to do `data[, reps := 13][year(Time)==2016, reps := 11-month(Time)][rep(1:.N, reps)]`

Comment: why `ifelse` is slow?

Comment: @PeterChen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16275149/does-ifelse-really-calculate-both-of-its-vectors-every-time-is-it-slow