# How would I implement this countif in r?

Tags: r, dataframe

My two dataframes:

```
 df1
    Col1 
     A
     B
     C

 df2
    Col1 
     A  
     D  
     E  
     F
```

I would like to add a 2nd column, Col2, to df1 where each value in the column is 1 if it's respective value in Col1 is also in Col1 of df2. Thus df1 would look like this:

```
 df1
    Col1 Col2
     A    1
     B    0
     C    0
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the col2 to df2

```
df2$Col2 <- 1
```

Perform a left-join merge:

```
df3 <- merge(df1, df2, all.x=T, by='Col1')
```

Replace the NAs with zeros

```
df3$Col2[which(is.na(df3$Col2))] <- 0
```

df3 is now

```
  Col1 Col2
1    A    1
2    B    0
3    C    0
```

Edit: @ycw [has done it more concisely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45423348/how-would-i-implement-this-countif-in-r/45423426#45423426) using `as.numeric` and `%in%`.  I like his answer, but I thought I'd edit mine to include a version of his work that doesn't use dplyr:

It's as simple as `df1$Col2 <- as.numeric(df1$Col1 %in% df2$Col1)`.  Much better than mine!

Comment: Nice solution. And thanks for adding the base R solution of my approach.

Comment: Nice. Another verson: `df1$found = !is.na(merge(df1, transform(df2, z = 1), all.x = TRUE)$z)`. Note that `%in%` is restrictive compared to this answer (which allows for merging on more than just one column).

Answer (score 1):

`df3` is the final output.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- data_frame(Col1 = c("A", "B", "C"))
df2 <- data_frame(Col1 = c("A", "D", "E", "F"))

df3 <- df1 %>% mutate(Col2 = as.numeric(Col1 %in% df2$Col1))
```

Or the following approach is similar to HarlandMason's method but using `dplyr` and `tidyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df3 <- df2 %>%
  mutate(Col2 = 1) %>%
  right_join(df1, by = "Col1") %>%
  replace_na(list(Col2 = 0))
```

Comment: Alternative without dplyr: `df1$Col2 = as.numeric(df1$Col1 %in% df2$Col1)`

Comment: For some reason I'm getting:
    Error in library(dplyr) : there is no package called ‘dplyr’

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Have you installed dplyr as with `install.packages('dplyr')`

Comment: Nevermind, I used @Florian's answer and used cbind() to stick that back onto df1. Thanks @Florian!

Comment: @RaiderNAYSHUN Perhaps you can mark HarlandMason's answer to let others know this question has been answered.

Answer (score 1):

Two options using `data.table`

First one uses `%chin%` operator :

```r
library(data.table)
x = data.table(v = LETTERS[1:3])
y = data.table(v = c("A","D","E","F"))

x[, found:= v %chin% y$v]
x
#>    v found
#> 1: A  TRUE
#> 2: B FALSE
#> 3: C FALSE
```

The second one is built on merging behaviour:

```r
library(data.table)
x = data.table(v = LETTERS[1:3])
y = data.table(v = c("A","D","E","F"))

y[, found := TRUE]
x[, found:= y[.SD, .(ifelse(is.na(found), FALSE, TRUE)), on  = .(v)]]
x
#>    v found
#> 1: A  TRUE
#> 2: B FALSE
#> 3: C FALSE
```

---

**EDIT**: Based on @frank comment, you could simplify with no `ifelse` - it is the same

```r
x[, found:= y[.SD, !is.na(found), on  = .(v)]]
x
#>    v found
#> 1: A  TRUE
#> 2: B FALSE
#> 3: C FALSE
```

---

For understanding what happens, here is the inside code I built on:

```r
x[, found := NULL]
y[x, on = .(v)]
#>    v found
#> 1: A  TRUE
#> 2: B    NA
#> 3: C    NA
```

Comment: That's a nice idea for doing it. Fyi, `ifelse` is usually discouraged because of this https://stackoverflow.com/q/16275149/ In this case, I guess you could just use `!is.na(found)` instead.

Comment: Yes you're right. I don't know I missed it. I update the answer.