# If/Else List Comprehension in R

Tags: r, list-comprehension

I am trying to compute a vector in R using List Comprehension. I want to multiple elements that are smaller than 5 or larger than 90 by 10 and multiply the other elements by 0.1. Currently I have the if part but can't find sufficient information on the else part of a List Comprehension.

```
x <- 1:100
10 * x [x < 5 | x > 90]
```

Comment: Use `ifelse`: `newx <- ifelse(x < 5 | x > 90, x*10, x*0.1)`

Answer (score 1):

No `ifelse` needed ([keeping in mind that `ifelse` is generally sort of slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16275149/does-ifelse-really-calculate-both-of-its-vectors-every-time-is-it-slow)):

```
newx = .1 * x + 9.9 * x * (x < 5 | x > 90)
```

Or a bit harder to read but only need one comparison:

```
newx = .1 * x + 9.9 * x * (abs(x - 5 - 85/2) > 85/2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution which is very easy to read (but computationally not very fast) with my package listcompr:

```
library(listcompr)
gen.vector((if (x < 5 | x > 90) 10 else 0.1) * x, x = 1:100)
```