# concatenating column names with column data in R (using data.table)

Tags: r, data.table, concatenation, multiple-columns

I have a data.table as follows,

```
library(data.table)

dt<-structure(list(varx = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L
), vary = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L))
dt
    varx vary
 1:    0    0
 2:    1    0
 3:    0    0
 4:    0    0
 5:    1    1
 6:    0    0
 7:    1    1
 8:    0    0
 9:    0    0
10:    0    0
```

and I am trying to get the following output:

```
dt 
    varx    vary
1:  varx_n  vary_n
2:  varx_y  vary_n
3:  varx_n  vary_n
4:  varx_n  vary_n
5:  varx_y  vary_y
6:  varx_n  vary_n
7:  varx_y  vary_y
8:  varx_n  vary_n
9:  varx_n  vary_n
10: varx_n  vary_n
```

using the following code:

```
dt[,lapply(.SD, function(x){
  ifelse(x==1,paste0(.SD,"_y"),paste0(.SD,"_n"))
})]
```

However, I am not getting the desired output. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works:

```
dt[ , lapply(setNames(nm = names(.SD)), function(nm_j) 
  sprintf('%s_%s', nm_j, c('n', 'y')[.SD[[nm_j]] + 1L]))]
#       varx   vary
#  1: varx_n vary_n
#  2: varx_y vary_n
#  3: varx_n vary_n
#  4: varx_n vary_n
#  5: varx_y vary_y
#  6: varx_n vary_n
#  7: varx_y vary_y
#  8: varx_n vary_n
#  9: varx_n vary_n
# 10: varx_n vary_n
```

The problem with your approach is that, in `lapply(.SD, ...)`, in the scope of `FUN` the *name* of the current list element (i.e., the column name) is unknown. To get around this, we loop over column *names* whereby we can give ourselves access to *both* the column names *and* the contents of the columns.

The `setNames` part is just for convenience, it can easily be broken out if you find it too code-golfy -- it will create an object `c(varx = 'varx', vary = 'vary')`, which lets the output automatically get the right names. If we do `lapply(names(.SD), ...)`, we'll have to clean up the column names afterwards.

`c('n', 'y')[idx + 1L]` is a bit of a murky way of saying `ifelse(idx, 'y', 'n')` (one of the places where 0-based indexing would be nice); it can be replaced with that as you see fit. If your data is massive, you'll notice my version is [faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16275149/does-ifelse-really-calculate-both-of-its-vectors-every-time-is-it-slow).

Answer (score 6):

Use `Map` and a bit of `factor` labelling to pair each variable name with the `n/y` label required.

```
dt[, Map(paste, names(dt), lapply(.SD,factor,labels=c("n","y")), sep="_")]

#      varx   vary
# 1: varx_n vary_n
# 2: varx_y vary_n
# 3: varx_n vary_n
# 4: varx_n vary_n
# 5: varx_y vary_y
# 6: varx_n vary_n
# 7: varx_y vary_y
# 8: varx_n vary_n
# 9: varx_n vary_n
#10: varx_n vary_n
```

Answer (score 2):

in base `R`:

```
dt[dt==0] <- "_n" 
dt[dt=="1"] <- "_y" 
dt[] <- Map(paste0,names(dt),dt)
#       varx   vary
#  1: varx_n vary_n
#  2: varx_y vary_n
#  3: varx_n vary_n
#  4: varx_n vary_n
#  5: varx_y vary_y
#  6: varx_n vary_n
#  7: varx_y vary_y
#  8: varx_n vary_n
#  9: varx_n vary_n
# 10: varx_n vary_n
```