# Vectorised if/else construct to avoid calling expensive function when condition is FALSE?

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, lapply, non-standard-evaluation

## Background

I have a computationally expensive (and **SLOW**) function which is called from within another function which is part of a dplyr pipeline:

```
dat %>%
mutate_at(.vars = vars(dplyr::intersect(starts_with("locale"), ends_with("last_name"))), 
          .funs = funs(native_last_name_alpha(., Type))) %>% 
          {.} -> dat
```

The function does one of two things, depending on whether the variable `Type` (a character string) is match for "male" or "female". If there is a match, `native_last_name_alpha` will run the computationally expensive and **slow** function which does some other stuff. If there is no match, `native_last_name_alpha` will return `NA`. Currently, because this is vectorised, I'm using `if_else` and `case_when` to determine what should happen, for example:

```
native_last_name_alpha <- function(locale, type) {
  case_when(
    type == "male" ~ stringi::stri_trans_toupper(
      fake_single_alpha(locale = locale, 
                        request = "last_name_male", 
                        provider = "faker.providers.person")
    ),
    type == "female" ~ stringi::stri_trans_toupper(
      fake_single_alpha(locale = locale, 
                        request = "last_name_female", 
                        provider = "faker.providers.person")
    ),
    TRUE ~ NA_character_
  )
}
```

The problem is that the expensive function runs regardless of whether the condition evaluates to `TRUE` or `FALSE`, and this makes my script extremely slow to run.

## Digging deeper into if_else, ifelse, and case_when

I understand that the vectorised if/else statements `if_else` and `ifelse` (and `case_when`) don't work like a traditional if...else statement; *all* parts of the statement are evaluated and then the condition is used to splice together the results to be returned. For example, this code produces the following output and warnings:

```
v <- c(-100, -10, 10, 100)
ifelse(v > 0, log10(v), log10(-v))
```

> [1] 2 1 1 2
>
> Warning messages:
>
> 1: In ifelse(v > 0, log10(v), log10(-v)) : NaNs produced
>
> 2: In ifelse(v > 0, log10(v), log10(-v)) : NaNs produced

Both the return value if the condition is true, and the return value if the condition is false, are evaluated, and the condition is used to splice together the vector of results.

Consequently, my expensive and slow function is running many more times than actually required.

**How can I avoid this?**

## What I'd like

I'm seeking alternative vectorised implementations of `if_else` and `case_when` that only evaluates the result-if-true when the condition is true.

## What I've tried so far

I've tried writing my own vectorised implementations of `if_else`/`ifelse`, but with no success. I've also experimented with non-standard evaluation, but I don't know enough to make this work. I'm guessing that if I can get an `if_else` to return an *unevaluated* expression that I then evaluate later at an appropriate time (kind of like a freeze-dried function call) this might be part of the solution. But no joy so far.

Is there anything I've missed to do what I want easily? Or can someone offer some hints on an implementation? Thanks!

Comment: @joran `ifelse` does evaluate both possible responses *except* in cases where the `test` is either all TRUE or all FALSE: [Does ifelse really calculate both of its vectors every time? Is it slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16275149/903061)

Comment: @Gregor Yep, I was misremembering that exception.

Comment: However, I'm not sure about `dplyr::if_else` --- might be coded differently.