# Why does the ifelse() in R apply function when test is FALSE?

Tags: r

From a character column in a tibble, I'm trying to extract numbers and convert to numeric type using `ifelse()` to apply `as.numeric()` on values that do not contain letters (or "+").

While this example works, it returns a warning message:

```
library(dplyr)

tibble(a = c("0", "0.1", "abc")) %>% 
  mutate(b = ifelse(!grepl("[a-zA-Z\\+]+", a), as.numeric(a), NA))

# A tibble: 3 × 2
  a         b
  <chr> <dbl>
1 0       0  
2 0.1     0.1
3 abc    NA  
Warning message:
Problem while computing `b = ifelse(grepl("[a-zA-Z\\+]+", a), NA, as.numeric(a))`.
ℹ NAs introduced by coercion
```

Please help me understand why my script is still trying to convert the character value to numeric, and how I can fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in this strongly related question: [Does ifelse really calculate both of its vectors every time?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16275149/903061), `ifelse` (generally) calculates both responses for every entry, and then puts the appropriate ones together into the result vector. So even though `as.numeric("abc")` isn't in your results, it still tries to calculate it.

Which means that there probably isn't much point in using `ifelse()` here. Might as well simplify to `b = as.numeric(a)`, or if you want to avoid the warnings `b = suppressWarnings(as.numeric(a))`.

Comment: Thanks Gregor, interesting read. I had tried case_when(), which also returned the warning. Work around: use the ifelse() to copy the contents of a to b if the test is met, other wise b is NA. Then apply 'as.numeric()' to b.

Comment: Sure, that works too (though it seems equivalent and less efficient than `suppressWarnings()`)