# R ifelse in dplyr across evaluating condition it's not supposed to

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, lubridate

#### Update:

I fixed my reprex.

#### Original:

I have an `ifelse` statement as the function in an `across`. I'm getting an error on trying to calculate the fall-through value even in the case where the condition is true.

```r
library(tidyverse)

tibble(x = 1:3) %>%
  mutate(y = across(x, ~ifelse(.x==1, 1, days_in_month(.x-1))))
#> Error in `mutate()`:
#> ℹ In argument: `y = across(x, ~ifelse(.x == 1, 1, days_in_month(.x -
#>   1)))`.
#> Caused by error in `across()`:
#> ! Can't compute column `x`.
#> Caused by error in `month.numeric()`:
#> ! Values are not in 1:12
#> Backtrace:
#>      ▆
#>   1. ├─tibble(x = 1:3) %>% ...
#>   2. ├─dplyr::mutate(...)
#>   3. ├─dplyr:::mutate.data.frame(...)
#>   4. │ └─dplyr:::mutate_cols(.data, dplyr_quosures(...), by)
#>   5. │   ├─base::withCallingHandlers(...)
#>   6. │   └─dplyr:::mutate_col(dots[[i]], data, mask, new_columns)
#>   7. │     └─mask$eval_all_mutate(quo)
#>   8. │       └─dplyr (local) eval()
#>   9. ├─dplyr::across(x, ~ifelse(.x == 1, 1, days_in_month(.x - 1)))
#>  10. │ ├─base::withCallingHandlers(...)
#>  11. │ └─fn(col, ...)
#>  12. │   ├─base::ifelse(.x == 1, 1, days_in_month(.x - 1))
#>  13. │   └─lubridate::days_in_month(.x - 1)
#>  14. │     ├─lubridate::month(x, label = TRUE, locale = "C")
#>  15. │     └─lubridate:::month.numeric(x, label = TRUE, locale = "C")
#>  16. │       └─base::stop("Values are not in 1:12")
#>  17. └─base::.handleSimpleError(...)
#>  18.   └─dplyr (local) h(simpleError(msg, call))
#>  19.     └─rlang::abort(bullets, call = error_call, parent = cnd)

tibble(x = 1:3) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(y = ifelse(x==1, 1, days_in_month(x-1)))
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#> # Rowwise:
#>       x     y
#>   <int> <dbl>
#> 1     1     1
#> 2     2    31
#> 3     3    28
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: What do you expect this code is doing? Why use `across` if you just use `x` inside the anonymous function? Did you intend to use `.x`? In the `across` example, `x` is always a length 3 integer vector. In the bottom example, `x` is a length 1 integer vector.

Comment: @IanCampbell -- yup. I was meaning to use `.x`. I have fixed it.

Comment: @neilfws -- so, the problem isn't being able to do the thing I want to do. The problem is understanding this odd behavior in `across`. So I created a simplistic example.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies on how `ifelse()` itself works. It evaluates the whole vector in the `yes` and `no` expressions then returns the values that fit the `condition`, as @RitchieSacramento notes in the comments (also further discussion about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16275201/22355221). So `days_in_month(0:2)` is actually being evaluated and thus causing the error.

- So instead of `ifelse`, you might wanna just use the basic `if(){}else{}` and vectorize it:

```
library(tidyverse)

foo=function(x){
  if(x==1){1}else{days_in_month(x)}
}

foo = Vectorize(foo)

tibble(x = 1:3) %>%
  mutate(y = across(x, ~foo(x)))
```

- on the other hand, @RitchieSacramento suggests a much direct solution according to your code which replaces the error-causing-part, the "0", to become "1" so that `days_in_month` does not throw an error.

```
tibble(x = 1:3) %>% 
  mutate(across(x, ~ifelse(.x==1, 1, days_in_month(pmax(1, .x-1)))))
```

Then performance-wise, here are the statistics,

```
library(rbenchmark)
set.seed(2023)
foo=function(x){
    if(x==1) {1}else{ days_in_month(x-1)}
  }
foo = Vectorize(foo)
x = sample(1:13,100,replace=T)
benchmark(
vectorize_if={
  tibble(x ) %>%
    mutate(y = across(x, ~foo(x)))
},
method2={
  tibble(x) %>%   mutate(across(x, ~ifelse(x==1, 1, days_in_month(pmax(1, x-1)))))  
})

          test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
2      method2          100    0.37    1.000      0.28        0         NA        NA
1 vectorize_if          100    0.86    2.324      0.56        0         NA        NA
```

Comment: This is not related to `mutate()`, the issue lies with `ifelse()` where the `yes` and `no` arguments are evaluated using the *full* condition vector if any test value is `TRUE` or `FALSE`.  The only times the `yes` or `no` arguments do not get evaluated is when `test` returns all `TRUE` or all `FALSE`. OP's `no` argument is fully evaluated as `days_in_month(0:2)` and as there is no month `0` throws an error.

Comment: @RitchieSacramento So the error is `ifelse()` in `mutate()`? That's why I vectorize the `ifelse()`. But I guess blaming the `mutate()` itself is bad reasoning. Thank you for the heads up.

Comment: Vectorizing works because it results in all tests being length 1, in which case only one condition ever gets evaluated.  But it is bad practice because `ifelse()` is already vectorized, and you are in effect de-vectorizing it and making an efficient function much less efficient.  Better to do something like `tibble(x = 1:3) %>%
  mutate(across(x, ~ifelse(.x==1, 1, days_in_month(pmax(1, .x-1)))))` which addresses the root cause of the error.

Comment: Ohh I'm starting to get the point. I had a misconception about why `x=1:3; ifelse(x==1, 1, days_in_month(x-1))` throws an error. You may provide an answer to the post and I will delete mine unless you simply wish to improve my answer with your good comment. I'm not completely well-versed on how SO works.

Comment: Happy for you to improve yours.

Comment: @RitchieSacramento you should post something, if only it is just your comments in a more formal form

Comment: You should not vectorize `ifelse`. It is already vectorized.

Comment: @Onyambu Thank you for the comment. @RitchieSacramento said so as well. Now I understand the difference of vectorized-`if` and `ifelse`

Comment: Just an additional comment to say that a benchmark on 3 values is not meaningful - you need to test on a much longer vector otherwise all you're really seeing is function overhead.  Also, move the `foo` function definition outside of the benchmark.

Comment: Ahh I see. There's a really big difference on larger length of values. Many thanks again. @RitchieSacramento

Answer (score 0):

As noted elsewhere, this isn't an issue with `mutate` or `across` but rather how you're using `ifelse`. It evaluates every value, but `days_in_month(0)` produces an error.

We can fix the input so it doesn't pass nonsensical month values like `0` into the `days_in_month` function. You could do that by using some math to convert to "prior month", so that `1:12` becomes `c(12, 1:11)`, for instance with `(.x - 2) %% 12 + 1`. Then the original function is fine. For instance:

```
days_in_month((1:12 - 2) %% 12 + 1)

#Dec Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov 
# 31  31  28  31  30  31  30  31  31  30  31  30
```

So:

```
tibble(x = 1:3) %>%
  mutate(across(x, ~ifelse(
    .x==1, 1, days_in_month((.x - 2) %% 12 + 1)),
    .names = "{.col}_y"))

# A tibble: 3 × 2
      x   x_y
  <int> <dbl>
1     1     1
2     2    31
3     3    28
```