# Move a column conveniently

Tags: r, dplyr

There are great questions and answers on how to move a column to the first or last place.

Using `dplyr` The best answers are respectively analog to :

```
iris2 <- iris %>% head(2)
iris2 %>% select( Sepal.Width, everything()) # move Sepal.Width to first
#   Sepal.Width Sepal.Length Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
# 1         3.5          5.1          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 2         3.0          4.9          1.4         0.2  setosa

iris2 %>% select(-Sepal.Width, Sepal.Width) # move Sepal.Width to last
#   Sepal.Length Petal.Length Petal.Width Species Sepal.Width
# 1          5.1          1.4         0.2  setosa         3.5
# 2          4.9          1.4         0.2  setosa         3.0
```

However I didn't find any easy way to move a column after or before a given one.

Expected output :

```
iris2 %>% move_at(Species, Sepal.Width, side = "before") 
#   Sepal.Length Species Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
# 1          5.1  setosa         3.5          1.4         0.2
# 2          4.9  setosa         3.0          1.4         0.2

iris2 %>% move_at(Species, Sepal.Width, side = "after")
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Species Petal.Length Petal.Width
# 1          5.1         3.5  setosa          1.4         0.2
# 2          4.9         3.0  setosa          1.4         0.2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To complete the answers, there is a function called `relocate()` since `dplyr 1.0.0`:

```r
library(dplyr)

iris %>% 
  head(n = 2) %>%
  relocate(Species, .before = Sepal.Width)
#>   Sepal.Length Species Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#> 1          5.1  setosa         3.5          1.4         0.2
#> 2          4.9  setosa         3.0          1.4         0.2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Indeed, that's the way to do it now. Thanks for the update

Answer (score 15):

*UPDATE : using `rlang::enquo` I could make it much better, then using @Zsombor's answer I could make it much shorter and more elegant. old solution (in base R) at the end of answer*

```
#' Move column or selection of columns
#'
#' Column(s) described by \code{cols} are moved before (default) or after the reference 
#'   column described by \code{ref}
#'
#' @param data A \code{data.frame}
#' @param cols unquoted column name or numeric or selection of columns using a select helper
#' @param ref unquoted column name
#' @param side \code{"before"} or \code{"after"}
#'
#' @return A data.frame with reordered columns
#' @export
#'
#' @examples
#' iris2 <- head(iris,2)
#' move(iris2, Species, Sepal.Width)
#' move(iris2, Species, Sepal.Width, "after")
#' move(iris2, 5, 2)
#' move(iris2, 4:5, 2)
#' move(iris2, one_of("Sepal.Width","Species"), Sepal.Width)
#' move(iris2, starts_with("Petal"), Sepal.Width)
move <- function(data, cols, ref, side = c("before","after")){
  if(! requireNamespace("dplyr")) 
    stop("Make sure package 'dplyr' is installed to use function 'move'")
  side <- match.arg(side)
  cols <- rlang::enquo(cols)
  ref  <- rlang::enquo(ref)
  if(side == "before") 
    dplyr::select(data,1:!!ref,-!!ref,-!!cols,!!cols,dplyr::everything()) 
  else
    dplyr::select(data,1:!!ref,-!!cols,!!cols,dplyr::everything())
}
```

examples:

```
iris2 %>% move(Species, Sepal.Width)
#   Sepal.Length Species Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
# 1          5.1  setosa         3.5          1.4         0.2
# 2          4.9  setosa         3.0          1.4         0.2

iris2 %>% move(Species, Sepal.Width, "after")
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Species Petal.Length Petal.Width
# 1          5.1         3.5  setosa          1.4         0.2
# 2          4.9         3.0  setosa          1.4         0.2

iris2 %>% move(5, 2)
#   Sepal.Length Species Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
# 1          5.1  setosa         3.5          1.4         0.2
# 2          4.9  setosa         3.0          1.4         0.2

iris2 %>% move(4:5, 2)
#   Sepal.Length Petal.Width Species Sepal.Width Petal.Length
# 1          5.1         0.2  setosa         3.5          1.4
# 2          4.9         0.2  setosa         3.0          1.4

iris2 %>% move(one_of("Sepal.Width","Species"), Sepal.Width)
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Species Petal.Length Petal.Width
# 1          5.1         3.5  setosa          1.4         0.2
# 2          4.9         3.0  setosa          1.4         0.2

iris2 %>% move(starts_with("Petal"), Sepal.Width)
#   Sepal.Length Petal.Length Petal.Width Sepal.Width Species
# 1          5.1          1.4         0.2         3.5  setosa
# 2          4.9          1.4         0.2         3.0  setosa
```

---

*Old solution*

Here's a simple solution using only base R programming :

```
move_at <- function(data, col, ref, side = c("before","after")){
  side = match.arg(side)
  col_pos <- match(as.character(substitute(col)),names(data))
  ref_pos <- match(as.character(substitute(ref)),names(data))
  sorted_pos <- c(col_pos,ref_pos)
  if(side =="after") sorted_pos <- rev(sorted_pos)
  data[c(setdiff(seq_len(ref_pos-1),col_pos),
         sorted_pos,
         setdiff(seq_along(data),c(seq_len(ref_pos),col_pos)))]
}

iris2 %>% move_at(Species, Sepal.Width)
#   Sepal.Length Species Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
# 1          5.1  setosa         3.5          1.4         0.2
# 2          4.9  setosa         3.0          1.4         0.2

iris2 %>% move_at(Species, Sepal.Width, "after")
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Species Petal.Length Petal.Width
# 1          5.1         3.5  setosa          1.4         0.2
# 2          4.9         3.0  setosa          1.4         0.2
```

Comment: Awesome. That's the second @Moody_Mudskipper function which I will incorporate in my utilities :) Thanks!

Comment: Honoured :). What's the first if I may ask ?

Comment: of course! that’s ‘get_age’ ;) https://stackoverflow.com/a/47529507/7941188

Answer (score 7):

This seems to work, regardless of original column order (thanks for the comment to @Moody_Mudskipper ):

```
iris %>% select(1:Sepal.Width, -Species, Species, everything()) %>% head(2)
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Species Petal.Length Petal.Width
#> 1          5.1         3.5  setosa          1.4         0.2
#> 2          4.9         3.0  setosa          1.4         0.2
iris %>% select(1:Sepal.Width, -Sepal.Width, -Species, Species, everything()) %>% head(2)
#>   Sepal.Length Species Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#> 1          5.1  setosa         3.5          1.4         0.2
#> 2          4.9  setosa         3.0          1.4         0.2
```

Comment: I'm choosing this as I made it the core of my own solution, and most users don't want a new function. See my answer below for a function permitting less verbose calls.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Thanks for accepting! Sure the function you wrote is much clearer to use in real code. To understand these two lines, you have to know quite a lot about tidyselect already, otherwise it's nonsense. So it's a great idea to hide the call in a function whose name describes what it is doing. I guess reordering columns isn't particularly in the focus of tidyverse, even though it's pretty important when exporting results.

Comment: yes, or when you want to explore the data visually as was the case that inspired this question. This discussion is relevant: https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/3051#issuecomment-324646580 , @hadey says "I don't think this is such a common operation that it needs it's own verb.", speaking about moving a column to the last spot. I've seen similar issues a few times on SO though.

Comment: The solution needs a correction, it doesn't work if you switch `Species` and `Sepal.width`, the right solutions are `iris %>% select(1:Sepal.Width,-Species, Species, everything()) %>% head(2)` and `iris %>% select(1:Sepal.Width, -Sepal.Width, -Species, Species, everything()) %>% head(2)`

Comment: I mean, it does work perfectly as it solves the example, but it would deserve a note to explain that it wouldn't if `Species` was located before `Sepal.Width` or it could be misleading. Following the pattern for my comment above should be robust however.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I've edited the answer. However, this code looks even worse now. I'm pretty sure that select was not designed for this purpose, and complex column reorderings should be done using base R syntax, like your example below.

Answer (score 3):

Just for the record, another solution would be

```
library(tidyverse)
data(iris)

iris %>% 
  select(-Species) %>% 
  add_column(Specis = iris$Species, .before = "Petal.Length") %>% 
  head()

#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Specis Petal.Length Petal.Width
#> 1          5.1         3.5 setosa          1.4         0.2
#> 2          4.9         3.0 setosa          1.4         0.2
#> 3          4.7         3.2 setosa          1.3         0.2
#> 4          4.6         3.1 setosa          1.5         0.2
#> 5          5.0         3.6 setosa          1.4         0.2
#> 6          5.4         3.9 setosa          1.7         0.4
```

Created on 2018-08-31 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: That's a neat solution as well, if it could leverage the stuff from `?dplyr::select_helpers` and would allow "adding" existing columns I would choose it.

Comment: Indeed, select-helpers would be nice. I have written a `move_columns()` function to my _sjmisc_ package. The function is available in the current GitHub-version, and also allows select-helpers. See examples here: https://strengejacke.github.io/sjmisc/reference/move_columns.html

Comment: You have got some awesome and very useful functions in that package, Daniel!

Comment: Thanks, glad you like it! :-)

Answer (score 2):

I found an interesting function ([moveMe](https://github.com/mrdwab/SOfun/blob/master/R/moveMe.R), written by @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1) that closely fits the problem:

```
source('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mrdwab/SOfun/master/R/moveMe.R')

head(iris[ moveMe(names(iris), 'Species before Sepal.Width') ], 2)
#   Sepal.Length Species Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
# 1          5.1  setosa         3.5          1.4         0.2
# 2          4.9  setosa         3.0          1.4         0.2


head(iris[ moveMe(names(iris), 'Species after Sepal.Width') ], 2)
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Species Petal.Length Petal.Width
# 1          5.1         3.5  setosa          1.4         0.2
# 2          4.9         3.0  setosa          1.4         0.2
```

It also allows for more complex instructions:

```
head(iris[ moveMe(names(iris), 'Species after Sepal.Width; Petal.Width first; Sepal.Length last') ], 2)
#   Petal.Width Sepal.Width Species Petal.Length Sepal.Length
# 1         0.2         3.5  setosa          1.4          5.1
# 2         0.2         3.0  setosa          1.4          4.9
```

Answer (score 0):

Another Base R solution (not sure how it benchmarks against the others).

```
# Function to move column names before or after another column name: 
# .move_vec_name_to => function 
.move_vec_name_to <- function(vec_names, move_vec_name, near_vec_name, side = c("before", "after")){
  # Resolve the side to move the col vector to: 
  # .side => character scalar
  .side <- match.arg(side)
  # Resolve the number of column vectors: n => integer scalar
  n <- length(vec_names)
  # Resolve the index of the col vector to be moved: 
  # move_vec_idx => integer scalar
  move_vec_idx <- which(vec_names == move_vec_name)
  # Resolve the index of where the col vector is to be 
  # moved to: near_vec_idx => integer scalar
  near_vec_idx <- which(vec_names == near_vec_name)
  # If we want to move something before or after and there is no need:
  if((move_vec_idx <= near_vec_idx & .side == "before") || (near_vec_idx <= move_vec_idx && .side == "after")){
    # Keep the names the same: new_col_name_vec => character vector 
    new_col_name_vec <- vec_names
    # Otherwise: 
  }else{
    # Drop the name of the vector to be moved from the col 
    # name vector: vec_wo_move_vec => character vector
    vec_wo_move_vec <- vec_names[-move_vec_idx]
    # Resolve the new column name vector: 
    # if we want to move the column before a given col vector: 
    if(.side == "before"){
      # new_col_name_vec => character vector
      new_col_name_vec <- c(
        vec_wo_move_vec[seq_len(near_vec_idx - 1)], 
        move_vec_name,
        near_vec_name, 
        vec_wo_move_vec[seq(pmin(near_vec_idx + 1, n), length(vec_names))]
      )[seq_len(n)]
      # Otherwise if we want to move it after: 
    }else{
      # new_col_name_vec => character vector
      new_col_name_vec <- c(
        vec_wo_move_vec[seq_len(pmax(near_vec_idx-2, 0))], 
        near_vec_name, 
        move_vec_name,
        vec_wo_move_vec[seq(pmax(near_vec_idx, 1), n, 1)]
      )[seq_len(n)]
    }
  }
  # Explicitly define the returned object: 
  # character vector => env
  return(new_col_name_vec)
}

# Function to move multiple vector names to a certain side of another vector name: 
# .move_vec_names_to => function 
.move_vec_names_to <- function(vec_names, move_vec_names, near_vec_name, side = c("before", "after")){
  # Resolve the side: .side => character vector
  .side <- match.arg(side)
  # Reverse the input vectors to be moved: .move_vec_names => character vector
  .move_vec_names <- if(.side == "after"){
    rev(move_vec_names)
  }else{
    move_vec_names
  }
  # Set the termination case: 
  if(length(.move_vec_names) <= 1){
    # Return vector names with columns moved: character vector => env
    return(
      .move_vec_name_to(
        vec_names, 
        .move_vec_names, 
        near_vec_name, 
        .side
      )
    )
    # Otherwise: 
  }else{
    # Apply the column movement function recursively: 
    # character vector => env
    return(
      .move_vec_name_to(
        .move_vec_name_to(
          vec_names, 
          .move_vec_names[1], 
          near_vec_name, 
          .side
        ), 
        .move_vec_names[-1], 
        near_vec_name, 
        .side
      )
    )
  }
}

# Function to move column vector before or after another column vector: 
# move_to => function
move_to <- function(df, move_vec_name, near_vec_name, side = c("before", "after")){
  # Resolve the side to move the col vector to: 
  # .side => character scalar
  .side <- match.arg(side)
  # Apply vector name move function: df => data.frame
  df <- if(length(move_vec_name) > 1){
    df[,.move_vec_names_to(colnames(df), move_vec_name, near_vec_name, .side), drop = FALSE]
  }else{
    df[,.move_vec_name_to(colnames(df), move_vec_name, near_vec_name, .side), drop = FALSE]
  }
  # Explicitly define the returned object: 
  # data.frame => env
  return(df)
}


# Function to test the move_to user defined function: 
# test_single_col_move_to => function 
test_single_col_move_to <- function(df){
  # Import required pacakage:
  library(dplyr)
  # Generate a data.frame of test cases: 
  # test_val_df => data.frame
  test_val_df <- setNames(
    expand.grid(
      names(df), 
      names(df),
      c("before", "after")
    ),
    c(
      "move_vec",
      "near_vec", 
      "side"
    )
  )
  # Convert vals to chars: test_val_df => data.frame
  test_val_df[] <- lapply(
    test_val_df, 
    as.character
  )
  # Test all vector names in iris are in the resulting df 
  # and that all names are where they are supposed to be: 
  # test_vec_names => list of boolean vectors
  test_vec_names <- lapply(
    seq_len(
      nrow(test_val_df)
    ), 
    function(i){
      # Resolve the test values: 
      move_vec <- test_val_df[i, 1, drop = TRUE] 
      near_vec <- test_val_df[i, 2, drop = TRUE] 
      side <- test_val_df[i, 3, drop = TRUE]
      # Test 1 base R functionality:
      test1 <- names(
        move_to(
          df, 
          move_vec,
          near_vec,
          side
        )
      )
      # Test 2 base R functionality: 
      test2 <- df |> move_to(move_vec, near_vec, side) |> names()
      # Test 3 dplyr functionality:
      test3 <- df %>% move_to(move_vec, near_vec, side) %>% names
      # Test 4 dply functionality: 
      test4 <- df %>% move_to(., move_vec, near_vec, side) %>% names
      # Store all tests in a list: test_list => list of character vectors
      test_list <- list(test1, test2, test3, test4)
      # list of tests: list of lists of boolean vectors => env
      list(
        # Test all names in new col vectors are in df: 
        unlist(Map(function(x){all(x %in% names(df))}, test_list)),
        # Test befores & afters: 
        unlist(Map(function(y){
          ifelse(
            side == "before", 
            which(y == move_vec) <= which(y == near_vec), 
            which(y == move_vec) >= which(y == near_vec)
          )
        },
        test_list
        )
        )
      )
    }
  )
  # Resolve if all tests have been passed:
  # tests_passed => boolean scalar
  tests_passed <- all(unlist(test_vec_names))
  # Explicitly define returned argument: 
  # boolean scalar => env
  return(tests_passed)
}

# Test any move of any column vector to anywhere on iris: 
# boolean scalar => stdout(console)
test_single_col_move_to(iris)

# Apply the function to move multiple vectors before or after another
# vector: data.frame => stdout(console)
names(iris)
move_to(
  iris, 
  c("Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length"), 
  "Species", 
  "after"
)
move_to(
  iris, 
  c("Species", "Petal.Width"), 
  "Petal.Length", 
  "before"
)
```

Comment: A couple usage examples would make this answer friendlier.

Comment: @GregorThomas A few months late but added some functionality, made it more efficient, and added some usage examples