# Make a feature the first column in data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame, say mtcars:

```
> glimpse(mtcars)
Observations: 32
Variables: 11
$ mpg  <dbl> 21.0, 21.0, 22.8, 21.4, 18.7, 18.1, 14.3, 24.4, 22.8, 19.2, 17.8, 16.4, 17.3, 15.2, 10.4, 10.4, 14.7, 32.4, 30.4, 33.9, 21.5, 15.5, 15.2, 13.3, 19.2, …
$ cyl  <dbl> 6, 6, 4, 6, 8, 6, 8, 4, 4, 6, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 8, 8, 8, 4, 4, 4, 8, 6, 8, 4
$ disp <dbl> 160.0, 160.0, 108.0, 258.0, 360.0, 225.0, 360.0, 146.7, 140.8, 167.6, 167.6, 275.8, 275.8, 275.8, 472.0, 460.0, 440.0, 78.7, 75.7, 71.1, 120.1, 318.0,…
$ hp   <dbl> 110, 110, 93, 110, 175, 105, 245, 62, 95, 123, 123, 180, 180, 180, 205, 215, 230, 66, 52, 65, 97, 150, 150, 245, 175, 66, 91, 113, 264, 175, 335, 109
$ drat <dbl> 3.90, 3.90, 3.85, 3.08, 3.15, 2.76, 3.21, 3.69, 3.92, 3.92, 3.92, 3.07, 3.07, 3.07, 2.93, 3.00, 3.23, 4.08, 4.93, 4.22, 3.70, 2.76, 3.15, 3.73, 3.08, …
$ wt   <dbl> 2.620, 2.875, 2.320, 3.215, 3.440, 3.460, 3.570, 3.190, 3.150, 3.440, 3.440, 4.070, 3.730, 3.780, 5.250, 5.424, 5.345, 2.200, 1.615, 1.835, 2.465, 3.5…
$ qsec <dbl> 16.46, 17.02, 18.61, 19.44, 17.02, 20.22, 15.84, 20.00, 22.90, 18.30, 18.90, 17.40, 17.60, 18.00, 17.98, 17.82, 17.42, 19.47, 18.52, 19.90, 20.01, 16.…
$ vs   <dbl> 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1
$ am   <dbl> 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
$ gear <dbl> 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4
$ carb <dbl> 4, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 2, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 2, 1, 2, 2, 4, 6, 8, 2
```

Suppose I want to reorder the features so that hp is the first column to appear in the data frame as opposed to mpg.

I know that I could use dplyr like so:

```
> glimpse(mtcars %>% select_at(vars(hp, mpg:disp, drat:carb)))
Observations: 32
Variables: 11
$ hp   <dbl> 110, 110, 93, 110, 175, 105, 245, 62, 95, 123, 123, 180, 180, 180, 205, 215, 230, 66, 52, 65, 97, 150, 150, 245, 175, 66, 91, 113, 264, 175, 335, 109
$ mpg  <dbl> 21.0, 21.0, 22.8, 21.4, 18.7, 18.1, 14.3, 24.4, 22.8, 19.2, 17.8, 16.4, 17.3, 15.2, 10.4, 10.4, 14.7, 32.4, 30.4, 33.9, 21.5, 15.5, 15.2, 13.3, 19.2, …
$ cyl  <dbl> 6, 6, 4, 6, 8, 6, 8, 4, 4, 6, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 8, 8, 8, 4, 4, 4, 8, 6, 8, 4
$ disp <dbl> 160.0, 160.0, 108.0, 258.0, 360.0, 225.0, 360.0, 146.7, 140.8, 167.6, 167.6, 275.8, 275.8, 275.8, 472.0, 460.0, 440.0, 78.7, 75.7, 71.1, 120.1, 318.0,…
$ drat <dbl> 3.90, 3.90, 3.85, 3.08, 3.15, 2.76, 3.21, 3.69, 3.92, 3.92, 3.92, 3.07, 3.07, 3.07, 2.93, 3.00, 3.23, 4.08, 4.93, 4.22, 3.70, 2.76, 3.15, 3.73, 3.08, …
$ wt   <dbl> 2.620, 2.875, 2.320, 3.215, 3.440, 3.460, 3.570, 3.190, 3.150, 3.440, 3.440, 4.070, 3.730, 3.780, 5.250, 5.424, 5.345, 2.200, 1.615, 1.835, 2.465, 3.5…
$ qsec <dbl> 16.46, 17.02, 18.61, 19.44, 17.02, 20.22, 15.84, 20.00, 22.90, 18.30, 18.90, 17.40, 17.60, 18.00, 17.98, 17.82, 17.42, 19.47, 18.52, 19.90, 20.01, 16.…
$ vs   <dbl> 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1
$ am   <dbl> 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
$ gear <dbl> 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4
$ carb <dbl> 4, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 2, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 2, 1, 2, 2, 4, 6, 8, 2
```

Is there a shorter, more elegant way of doing this?

(tidyverse or base r solutions particularly welcome)

Comment: `mtcars %>% select(hp, everything())`

Comment: You generally only need `select_at` for helper functions, like `starts_with`. For simple column selection and bare column names, just use `select`

Comment: Tyank you @camille. I never knew about everything(). I'll accept as answer if you want some SO karma brownie points?

Comment: Related [Move a column conveniently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52096919/move-a-column-conveniently)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dplyr` imports the `tidyselect` helper function `everything`, which, as its name implies, selects everything. This can be used in combination with other column selection, so that in this case, you select `hp`, then everything—since a column can only occur once, this takes on the meaning `hp` and then everything *else*.

```r
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>%
  select(hp, everything()) %>%
  head()
#>                    hp  mpg cyl disp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Mazda RX4         110 21.0   6  160 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> Mazda RX4 Wag     110 21.0   6  160 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#> Datsun 710         93 22.8   4  108 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#> Hornet 4 Drive    110 21.4   6  258 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#> Hornet Sportabout 175 18.7   8  360 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#> Valiant           105 18.1   6  225 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

A couple base R ways could involve `cbind`ing columns based on position. In this case, `hp` is the 4th column, so I bind together the 4th column of `mtcars` with everything *but* the 4th column of `mtcars` (same output as above):

```r
cbind(mtcars[4], mtcars[-4])
```

Or based on name, where I'm subsetting first for column names equal to `"hp"`, then not equal to `"hp"`:

```r
cbind(mtcars[names(mtcars) == "hp"], mtcars[names(mtcars) != "hp"])
```

I'm sure there are other base R ways as well--definitely could rig something up with `subset`.

Answer (score 2):

```r
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% 
  select(hp, everything())
#>                      hp  mpg cyl  disp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Mazda RX4           110 21.0   6 160.0 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> Mazda RX4 Wag       110 21.0   6 160.0 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#> Datsun 710           93 22.8   4 108.0 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#> Hornet 4 Drive      110 21.4   6 258.0 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#> Hornet Sportabout   175 18.7   8 360.0 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#> Valiant             105 18.1   6 225.0 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
#> Duster 360          245 14.3   8 360.0 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
#> Merc 240D            62 24.4   4 146.7 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
#> Merc 230             95 22.8   4 140.8 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
#> Merc 280            123 19.2   6 167.6 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
#> Merc 280C           123 17.8   6 167.6 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
#> Merc 450SE          180 16.4   8 275.8 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
#> Merc 450SL          180 17.3   8 275.8 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
#> Merc 450SLC         180 15.2   8 275.8 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
#> Cadillac Fleetwood  205 10.4   8 472.0 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
#> Lincoln Continental 215 10.4   8 460.0 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
#> Chrysler Imperial   230 14.7   8 440.0 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
#> Fiat 128             66 32.4   4  78.7 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
#> Honda Civic          52 30.4   4  75.7 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
#> Toyota Corolla       65 33.9   4  71.1 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
#> Toyota Corona        97 21.5   4 120.1 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
#> Dodge Challenger    150 15.5   8 318.0 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2
#> AMC Javelin         150 15.2   8 304.0 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2
#> Camaro Z28          245 13.3   8 350.0 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4
#> Pontiac Firebird    175 19.2   8 400.0 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2
#> Fiat X1-9            66 27.3   4  79.0 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
#> Porsche 914-2        91 26.0   4 120.3 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
#> Lotus Europa        113 30.4   4  95.1 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
#> Ford Pantera L      264 15.8   8 351.0 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4
#> Ferrari Dino        175 19.7   6 145.0 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6
#> Maserati Bora       335 15.0   8 301.0 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
#> Volvo 142E          109 21.4   4 121.0 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>