# calculate age from column birthdate and specified time in r

Tags: r, timestamp, data-manipulation

Calculate age from given column `birth_date` and specified date `"2017-01-01"` with format `"%y-%m-%d"` in R.

```
name birth_date
 a    1964-09-01
 b    1977-01-02
 c    1977-01-04
 d    1967-01-02
 e    1977-04-02
 f    1945-01-02

 x <- data.frame("name" =c("a","b","c","d","e","f"), "birth_date" = c("1964-09-01","1977-01-02","1977-01-04","1967-01-02","1977-04-02","1945-01-02"))
x

difftime(as.Date(x$birth_date),as.Date(2017-01-01), units = "years")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31126726/efficient-and-accurate-age-calculation-in-years-months-or-weeks-in-r-given-b

Comment: Or even https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611314/calculate-ages-in-r

Answer (score 3):

The following function needs package `lubridate`.
It has 2 arguments:

1. A vector of dates.
2. A base date, from which to compute the age. Defaults to the current system date.

The first call uses the default `base`.
The second call passes the base date in the question as the second argument.

```
library(lubridate)

age <- function(birth, base = Sys.Date()){
  i <- interval(birth, base)
  p <- as.period(i)
  year(p)
}

age(x$birth_date)
#[1] 54 42 42 52 42 74

age(x$birth_date, "2017-01-01")
#[1] 52 39 39 49 39 71
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `"years"` unit in `difftime`, the biggest one is `"weeks"`.

One way would be to calculate `difftime` in `"days"` and then divide by 365.2422 to get difference in years.

```
as.numeric(difftime(as.Date("2017-01-01"),as.Date(x$birth_date), units = "days")/365.2422)
#[1] 52.33514 39.99812 39.99264 49.99970 39.75170 71.99880
```

You could also use any other combination say select `units` as `"weeks"` and then convert it into equivalent `"year"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily using lubridate

```
x <- data.frame("name" =c("a","b","c","d","e","f"), "birth_date" = c("1964-09-01","1977-01-02","1977-01-04","1967-01-02","1977-04-02","1945-01-02"))
x

library(lubridate)

x$birth_date <- ymd(x$birth_date)

x$age <- year(Sys.Date()) - year(x$birth_date)
```

Hope its simple and helps

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems in your code. First, your date (2017-01-01) needs to be a string in quotes ('2017-01-01'). Second, you probably want to reverse the order of your dates. Third, difftime does not have a 'years' units. Without bringing in other packages or methods, here's the best approximation you can get for birthday age in years.

```
x <- data.frame("name" =c("a","b","c","d","e","f"), 
                "birth_date" = c("1964-09-01","1977-01-02","1977-01-04","1967-01-02","1977-04-02","1945-01-02"))

as.numeric(difftime(as.Date('2017-01-01'), as.Date(x$birth_date), units = "days")/365.2422)
```